# Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, storage, bigdata

I have a table in pg like so:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    a BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,               -- 8 b
    b SMALLINT,                         -- 2 b
    c SMALLINT,                         -- 2 b
    d REAL,                             -- 4 b
    e REAL,                             -- 4 b
    f REAL,                             -- 4 b
    g INTEGER,                          -- 4 b
    h REAL,                             -- 4 b
    i REAL,                             -- 4 b
    j SMALLINT,                         -- 2 b
    k INTEGER,                          -- 4 b
    l INTEGER,                          -- 4 b
    m REAL,                             -- 4 b
    CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (a)
);
```

The above adds up to 50 bytes per row. My experience is that I need another 40% to 50% for system overhead, without even any user-created indexes to the above. So, about 75 bytes per row. I will have many, many rows in the table, potentially upward of 145 billion rows, so the table is going to be pushing 13-14 terabytes. What tricks, if any, could I use to compact this table? My possible ideas below ...

Convert the `real` values to `integer`. If they can stored as `smallint`, that is a saving of 2 bytes per field.

Convert the columns b .. m into an array. I don't need to search on those columns, but I do need to be able to return one column's value at a time. So, if I need column g, I could do something like

```
SELECT a, arr[5] FROM t;
```

Would I save space with the array option? Would there be a speed penalty?

Any other ideas?

Comment: The PostgreSQL documentation advises to avoid the use of `real` and `double precision` types for [**exact floating point number representation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) (for example to store accounting values). Use instead the `numeric` data type. Just a tip in case those `real` values were to be used for accounting or exact result operations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see nothing to gain (and something to lose) in storing several numeric fields in an array.

The [size of each numerical type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) is clearly documented, you should simply use the smallest sized type compatible with your desired range-resolution; and that's about all you can do.

I don't think (but I'm not sure) if there is some byte alignment requirement for the columns along a row, in that  case a reordering of the columns could alter the space used - but I don't think so.

BTW, there is a fix overhead per row, about [23 bytes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/storage-page-layout.html).

Comment: As of 9.2, it's 24 bytes per row for the row header and 4 bytes for the page offset (stored in the page header), or 28 bytes per row. There are other items that can come in to play, for example 1 byte per 8 columns that support NULL values (NULL values are stored as a bitmask).

Comment: @Sean: This is not quite correct. The row header (HeapTupleHeader) has 23 Bytes, not 24, according to the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-page-layout.html): `There is a fixed-size header (occupying 23 bytes on most machines), followed by an optional null bitmap, an optional object ID field`. The difference is relevant, the NULL bitmask for tables with up to 8 columns fits into this one spare byte making NULL storage effectively free for these tables.

Comment: Correct, however due to alignment of data types, between bytes 23 and 24 there is almost certainly a hole, and starting on byte 25 an INT begins. So the header is only 23 bytes, but the space consumed is 24 bytes.

Answer (score 266):

### "Column Tetris"

Actually, you can do ***something***, but this needs deeper understanding. The keyword is ***alignment padding***. [Every data type has specific alignment requirements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html).

You can minimize space lost to padding ***between columns*** by ordering them favorably. The following (extreme) example would waste a lot of physical disk space:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    e int2    -- 6 bytes of padding after int2
  , a int8
  , f int2    -- 6 bytes of padding after int2
  , b int8
  , g int2    -- 6 bytes of padding after int2
  , c int8
  , h int2    -- 6 bytes of padding after int2
  , d int8)
```

To save **24 bytes** per row, use instead:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    a int8
  , b int8
  , c int8
  , d int8
  , e int2
  , f int2
  , g int2
  , h int2)   -- 4 int2 occupy 8 byte (MAXALIGN), no padding at the end
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5f80598fe34bb788764af0c1561a0372)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/84e13/84)</sub>

As a rule of thumb, if you put 8-byte columns first, then 4-bytes, 2-bytes and 1-byte columns last you can't go wrong.

`boolean`, `uuid` (!) and a few other types need no alignment padding. `text`, `varchar` and other "varlena" (variable length) types *nominally* require "int" alignment (4 bytes on most machines). But I observed no alignment padding in disk format (unlike in RAM). Eventually, I found the explanation in a [note in the source code:](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/pg__type_8h_source.html#l00166)

> Note also that we allow the nominal alignment to be violated when storing "packed" varlenas; the TOAST mechanism takes care of hiding that from most code.

So "int" alignment is only enforced when the (possibly compressed) datum including a single leading length-byte exceeds 127 bytes. Then varlena storage switches to four leading bytes and requires "int" alignment.

Normally, you may save a couple of bytes per row at best playing *"column tetris"*. None of this is necessary in most cases. But with billions of rows it can mean a couple of gigabytes easily.

You can test the actual column / row size with the function [**`pg_column_size()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE).
Some types occupy more space in RAM than on disk (compressed or "packed" format). You can get bigger results for constants (RAM format) than for table columns when testing the same value (or row of values vs. table row) with `pg_column_size()`.

Finally, some types can be [compressed or "toasted"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) (stored out of line) or both.

Where possible, move `NOT NULL` columns to the front, and columns with many `NULL` values to the rear. `NULL` values are served from the null bitmap directly, so their position in the row has no bearing on the access cost of `NULL` values, but they add a tiny cost for computing the offset of columns positioned to the right (further back in the row).

#### Overhead per tuple (row)

4 bytes per row for the item identifier - not subject to above considerations.
And at least 24 bytes (23 + padding) for the tuple header. [The manual on Database Page Layout:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)

> There is a fixed-size header (occupying 23 bytes on most machines),
> followed by an optional null bitmap, an optional object ID field, and
> the user data.

For the padding between header and user data, you need to know `MAXALIGN` on your server - typically 8 bytes on a 64-bit OS (or 4 bytes on a 32-bit OS). If you are not sure, check out [`pg_controldata`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgcontroldata.html).

Run the following in your *Postgres binary dir* to get a definitive answer:

```
./pg_controldata /path/to/my/dbcluster
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)

> The actual user data (columns of the row) begins at the offset
> indicated by `t_hoff`, which must always be a multiple of the `MAXALIGN`
> distance for the platform.

So you typically get the storage optimum by packing data in multiples of 8 bytes.

There is nothing to gain in the *example you posted*. It's already packed tightly. 2 bytes of padding after the last `int2`, 4 bytes at the end. You could consolidate the padding to 6 bytes at the end, which wouldn't change anything.

#### Overhead per data page

Data page size is typically 8 KB. Some overhead / bloat at this level, too: Remainders not big enough to fit another tuple, and more importantly dead rows or a percentage reserved with the [`FILLFACTOR` setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS).

There are a couple of other factors for size on disk to take into account:

- [How many records can I store in 5 MB of PostgreSQL on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885706/how-many-records-can-i-store-in-5-mb-of-postgresql-on-heroku)
- [Does not using NULL in PostgreSQL still use a NULL bitmap in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmap-in-the-header?lq=1)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43142/3684)

#### Array types?

With an **array** type like you were evaluating, you would add **24 bytes of overhead** for the type. Plus, array elements occupy space as usual. Nothing to gain there.

Comment: *As a rule of thumb, if you put 8-byte columns first, then 4-bytes, 2-bytes and 1-byte columns last you can't go wrong.* some legit cool advice.

Comment: This is a great/interesting answer, but one thing I don't get is why the order of column names in the `CREATE TABLE` is important at all. I didn't think it mattered. Why doesn't/can't postgres do this tetris optimization for you? Why is column order considered significant enough to keep as-defined?

Comment: @Russ: Because nobody implemented the division between logical and physical column order. [It's an open TODO item](https://wiki.postgresql.org/index.php?title=Alter_column_position&action=history), but not trivial since it's messing with system catalogs all over the place. Still true almost 6 years later. Since Postgres 9.3 a `VIEW` can serve to present a different column order for *simple* cases (writes are propagated automatically, too.)

Comment: Thanks, @Erwin. It still seems strange to leave to the user, though. I get that messing with system catalogs after table creation would be tricky, but it doesn't seem like it would be an issue if the reorder was done up front. What would be the issue with something like a storage parameter to achieve this? Something along the lines of `CREATE TABLE WITH column_reorder_ok` that implies "I don't care about logical column order, so fiddle with it however you like to optimize the table". Or, with your terminology, `WITH column_tetris_ok`. :)

Comment: @Russ: Sounds like a useful feature. A tool to reorder columns *before* the table gets created, which avoids complications from messing with system catalogs. Might also be implemented in any client software, a tool to optimize `CREATE TABLE` statement for minimal storage ...

Comment: FYI: your answer made it into the top 15 on https://news.ycombinator.com/ (2018-02-26). congratulations! comments are here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16471242

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: Thanks, this explains all the sudden love.

Comment: @Russ, I agree that something can be done, but it's complex. When you add and remove columns, the existing rows remain compatible because the ordering does not change. Newly added columns go onto the end of the row, while deleted columns never actually disappear, but are just disabled and effectively NULL'd. (And, as a benefit, open transactions can still see that column.) Certainly some optimization can be done with a logical-physical map on the table, or even on the disk-segment (or whatever its called).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Would it make difference in ordering of columns, if I know some of the columns will probably have null values in most rows or one still use the simple rule of thumb as suggested?

Comment: @DebasishMitra: Columns that are (almost) always NULL don't mess with alignment, as NULL is only represented as a single bit in the NULL bitmap. Their placement is unimportant. Might go to the end of the table for homeopathic gains.

Comment: I came to this post confused why changing VARCHAR(1) to CHAR(1) increased storage on Netezza Release 7.2.1.11-P1 [Build 4], but I confirmed column Tetris affects storage size also on Netezza.

Comment: +1 it may be worth it to say `put nullable columns at the end` as well because having nullable columns appear before non-null columns can make it [slower to access](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/heaptuple_8c_source.html#l01279) the non-null columns that come after the nullable column.

Comment: "boolean, uuid (!) and a few other types need no alignment padding" - unfortunately, booleans are subject to alignment too, as seen in the following test: https://dbfiddle.uk/_z-tgQYb

Comment: @Meglio: You are misinterpreting the test. The `bigint` columns cause the bloat, not the booleans.

Answer (score 17):

From this great documentation:  https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/on-rocks-and-sand/

For a table you already have, or perhaps one you're making in development, named `my_table`, this query will give the optimal order left to right.

```
SELECT a.attname, t.typname, t.typalign, t.typlen
FROM pg_class c
JOIN pg_attribute a ON (a.attrelid = c.oid)
JOIN pg_type t ON (t.oid = a.atttypid)
WHERE c.relname = 'my_table'
 AND a.attnum >= 0
ORDER BY t.typlen DESC
```

Comment: This query is really versatile. Does anybody know about a tool that automates the realignment of columns according to this query? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position

Comment: 4 @olidem https://github.com/NikolayS/postgres_dba, see my answer for an exaple

Answer (score 6):

Here is a cool tool regarding the Erwin's columns reordering suggestion: https://github.com/NikolayS/postgres_dba

It has the exact command for that -- p1:

[image]

Then it automatically shows you the real potential for columns reordering on all of your tables:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After reading the answers from [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/2171120) and [jboxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59553814/2171120) and the document linked in the latter, I improved slightly on the query to make it more versatile:

```
-- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tabletetris
    AS SELECT n.nspname, c.relname,
        a.attname, t.typname, t.typstorage, t.typalign, t.typlen
    FROM pg_class c
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON (n.oid = c.relnamespace)
    JOIN pg_attribute a ON (a.attrelid = c.oid)
    JOIN pg_type t ON (t.oid = a.atttypid)
    WHERE a.attnum >= 0
    ORDER BY n.nspname ASC, c.relname ASC,
        t.typlen DESC, t.typalign DESC, a.attnum ASC;
```

Use like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tabletetris WHERE relname='mytablename';
```

But you can add a filter on `nspname` (the schema the table is in).

I also added the storage kind, which is useful information in figuring out which of the `-1` ones to inline and/or oder where, and keep the relative order of existing columns with otherwise the same sort key.