# Using a single SQL correlated sub-query to get two columns

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, indexing, correlated-subquery

My problem is represented by the following query:

```
SELECT 
  b.row_id, b.x, b.y, b.something,
  (SELECT a.x FROM my_table a WHERE a.row_id = (b.row_id - 1), a.something != 42 ) AS source_x,
  (SELECT a.y FROM my_table a WHERE a.row_id = (b.row_id - 1), a.something != 42 ) AS source_y
FROM 
  my_table b
```

I'm using the same subquery statement twice, for getting both `source_x` and `source_y`.
That's why I'm wondering if it's possible to do it using one subquery only?

Because once I run this query on my real data (millions of rows) it seems to never finish and take hours, if not days (my connection hang up before the end).

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@DavidEG posted the best syntax for the query.

However, your problem is **definitely not just with the query technique**. A `JOIN` instead of two subqueries can speed up things by a factor of two at best. Most likely less. That doesn't explain "hours". Even with millions of rows, a decently set up Postgres should finish the simple query in seconds, not hours.

- First thing that stands out is the **syntax error** in your query:

  ```
  ... WHERE a.row_id = (b.row_id - 1), a.something != 42
  ```

  `AND` or `OR` is needed here, not a comma.
- Next thing to check are **indexes**. If `row_id` is not the primary key, you may not have an index on it. For optimum performance of this particular query create a [**multi-column index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(row_id, something)` like this:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX my_table_row_id_something_idx ON my_table (row_id, something)
  ```
- **If** the filter excludes the **same value** every time in `something != 42`you can also use a [**partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) instead for additional speed up:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX my_table_row_id_something_idx ON my_table (row_id)
  WHERE something != 42
  ```

  This will only make a substantial difference if `42` is a common value *or* `something` is a bigger column than just an integer. (An index with two `integer` columns normally occupies the the same size on disk as an index with just one, due to data alignment. See:

  - [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)
  - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)
- When performance is an issue, it is always a good idea to [**check your settings**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server). Standard settings in Postgres use minimal resources in many distributions and are not up to handling "millions of rows".
- Depending on your actual version of Postgres, an **[upgrade to a current version](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)** (9.1 at the time of writing) may help a lot.
- Ultimately, [**hardware**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Database_Hardware) is always a factor, too. Tuning and optimizing can only get you so far.

Comment: I trier the partial index and then @DavidEG query and had the new table very quickly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JulieFen-Chong: Cool. :) A fitting index is essential with millions of rows.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use this approach:

```
SELECT b.row_id
     , b.x
     , b.y
     , b.something
     , a.x
     , a.y
  FROM my_table b
  left join my_table a on a.row_id = (b.row_id - 1)
                      and a.something != 42
```

Answer (score 0):

old-fashioned syntax:

```
SELECT 
  b.row_id, b.x, b.y, b.something
  , a.x AS source_x
  , a.y AS source
FROM my_table b
    ,my_table a 
WHERE a.row_id = b.row_id - 1
  AND a.something != 42
  ;
```

Join-syntax:

```
SELECT 
  b.row_id, b.x, b.y, b.something
  , a.x AS source_x
  , a.y AS source
FROM my_table b
JOIN my_table a 
  ON (a.row_id = b.row_id - 1)
WHERE a.something != 42
  ;
```

Comment: You need `LEFT JOIN` for the requested result. DavidEG nailed it.

Comment: Yeah, the subqueries are supposed to return NULL if nothing is found. But is was too ugly, I suppose ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.row_id, b.x, b.y, b.something, a.x, a.y
  FROM my_table b
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT row_id + 1, x, y
      FROM my_table
      WHERE something != 42
  ) AS a ON a.row_id = b.row_id;
```

Comment: That would work, but is probably very slow, because you have to increment every row with `something != 42` (likely most of the "millions of rows") before the join, impeding the use of a standard index for the join as a side effect.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I see what you mean, I should have kept `a.row_id = b.row_id - 1` in the join condition instead. I was concentrating too much on moving the `something != 42` into the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres:

```
    SELECT 
      b.row_id, b.x, b.y, b.something,
      source_x,
      source_y
    FROM 
      my_table b,
LATERAL(SELECT a.x AS source_x, a.y AS source_y FROM my_table a WHERE a.row_id = (b.row_id - 1), a.something != 42 )
```

MsSQL

```
SELECT 
      b.row_id, b.x, b.y, b.something,
      source_x,
      source_y
    FROM 
      my_table b
OUTER APPLY(SELECT a.x AS source_x, a.y AS source_y FROM my_table a WHERE a.row_id = (b.row_id - 1), a.something != 42 )
```