# How to store year month in database?

Tags: database, postgresql

Is there a standard way to store year and month in a database ? I need to make some reports based on months and years.

I can't use dates and functions to extract months in real time because the tables are huge, so I need preprocessing.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if they've helped you

Answer (score 16):

I would go with [what @Michael proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169463/939860).

Extracting month and year from a `date` is super fast with [`EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) or [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html), there is probably no need for pre-processing.

A [`date` only occupies 4 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) on disk, hardly gets better than this.

A possible alternative could be 2 `integer` columns with column constraints to safeguard against illegal dates. Occupies 2 x 4 bytes.

Or even 2 `smallint` to save RAM and disk storage. Read about and understand *data alignment* in storage. In many cases you save nothing with `smallint` columns. See:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)

Best to go with a `date` column.

Comment: Not to mention that date arithmetic is simpler. Good luck finding all records between 2016, 9 and 2018, 3 using separate year+month columns.

Comment: @SalmanA: Postgres fully supports ROW comparison: `WHERE (year, month) BETWEEN (2016, 9) AND (2018, 3)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36465961/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982895/939860. Still, `date` is the way to go for many reasons.

Comment: that was just an example. Adding date interval, checking for date overlaps are other examples.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the most sensible is to use `date_trunc()` to month. You may also add a check constraint for `date_trunc()` being equal to the value if you want to.