# Incremental DISTINCT / GROUP BY operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

I have a simple two-stage SQL query that operators on two tables `A` and `B`, where I use a sub-select to retrieve a number of IDs of table `A` that are stored as foreign keys in B, using a (possibly complex) query on table B (and possibly other joined tables). Then, I want to simply return the first `x` IDs of `A`. I tried using a query like this:

```
SELECT sq.id
FROM  (
    SELECT a_id AS id, created_at
    FROM   B
    WHERE  ...
    ORDER  BY created_at DESC
    ) sq 
GROUP BY sq.id
ORDER BY max(sq.created_at) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

which is quite slow as Postgres seems to perform the `GROUP BY` / `DISTINCT` operation on the whole result set before limiting it. If I `LIMIT` the sub-query (e.g. to 100), the performance is just fine (as I'd expect), but of course it's no longer guaranteed that there will be at least 10 distinct `a_id` values in the resulting rows of `sq`.

Similarly, the query

```
SELECT a_id AS id
FROM   B
WHERE  ...
GROUP  BY id
ORDER  BY max(created_at) DESC
LIMIT  10
```

is quite slow as Postgres seems to perform a sequential scan on `B` instead of using an (existing) index. If I remove the `GROUP BY` clause it uses the index just fine.

The data in table `B` is such that most rows contain different `a_id`s, hence even without the `GROUP BY` most of the returned IDs will be different. The goal I pursue with the grouping is to assure that the result set always contains a given number of entries from `A`.

Is there a way to perform an "incremental `DISTINCT` / `GROUP BY`"? In my naive thinking it would suffice for Postgres to produce result rows and group them incrementally until it reaches the number specified by `LIMIT`, which in most cases should be nearly instantaneous as most `a_id` values are different. I tried various ways to query the data but so far I didn't find anything that works reliably.

The Postgres version is *9.6*, the data schema as follows:

```
                              Table "public.a"
 Column |       Type        |                   Modifiers                    
--------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------
 id     | bigint            | not null default nextval('a_id_seq'::regclass)
 bar    | character varying | 
Indexes:
    "a_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_a_bar" btree (bar)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "b" CONSTRAINT "b_a_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)

                                      Table "public.b"
   Column   |            Type             |                    Modifiers                     
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('b_id_seq'::regclass)
 foo        | character varying           | 
 a_id       | bigint                      | not null
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "b_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_b_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "ix_b_foo" btree (foo)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "b_a_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)
```

Comment: Please include an abbreviated schema and some sample data.  Also, show the full query, as these details matter.

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT***  a function. Writing `distinct (id)` makes no sense.

Comment: Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: `distinct(id)` seems to work just fine though as a query.

Comment: There may be a way. It's still unclear *which* 10 rows you want to retrieve exactly? Arbitrary / random pick? Or the first 10 sorted by `a_id` or by some other criteria? The two queries you display are not equivalent. Also: *always* declare your version of Postgres. And add the relevant definition of table `B` and relevant indexes you have.

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve just the first 10 rows. I suppose you mean that in the first query there is no ORDER BY in the outer statement? I should probably add the order by field to the inner query and then add a `ORDER BY` in the outer one.

Comment: Please define "first" in "first 10 rows".

Comment: The first x distinct elements, sorted by e.g. max(order_by_field).

Comment: .. which can be simplified to *first x distinct elements, sorted by `order_by_field`*

Comment: I edited the question and added a data schema, hope this clarifies it. My actual data schema is more complicated so I'm not sure if this simplified schema will reproduce the situation accurately though.

Comment: The best solution also depends on the nature of your `WHERE` clause, most importantly on *how selective* it can be, and whether we can use an index for it ...

Comment: I understand. It's just surprising that Postgres is not able to find a good query plan for this, as removing the GROUP BY clause (and accepting the possibility of duplicates in the `a_id` field) yields a very good query plan that uses all the correct indexes.

Comment: And do you really just need `a_id`, or the whole row containing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is much more complex than it might seem at a first glance.

If  ...

- your criteria are *not very selective* (much more than 10 distinct `a_id` qualify)
- you don't have *many* duplicate `a_id` in table `B` (like you stated)

then there is a very fast way.

To simplify a bit I assume `created_at` is also defined `NOT NULL`, or you need to do more.

```
WITH RECURSIVE top10 AS (
   ( -- extra parentheses required
   SELECT a_id, ARRAY[a_id] AS id_arr, created_at
   FROM   b
   WHERE  ...  -- your other filter conditions here
   ORDER  BY created_at DESC, a_id DESC  -- both NOT NULL
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL -- UNION ALL, not UNION, since we exclude dupes a priori
   (
   SELECT b.a_id, id_arr || b.a_id, b.created_at
   FROM   top10 t
   JOIN   b ON (b.created_at, b.a_id)
             < (t.created_at, t.a_id)  -- comparing ROW values
           AND  b.a_id <> ALL (t.id_arr)
   WHERE  ... -- repeat conditions
   ORDER  BY created_at DESC, a_id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   )
SELECT a_id
FROM   top10
LIMIT  10;
```

Ideally supported by an index on `(created_at DESC, a_id DESC)` (or just `(created_at, a_id)`).

Depending on your other `WHERE` conditions, other (partial?) indexes may serve even better.

This is particularly efficient for a small result set. Else, and depending on various other details, other solutions may be faster.

Related (with much more explanation):

- [Can spatial index help a “range - order by - limit” query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)
- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)
- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Great, I'll check it out! I also thought about using a recursive CTE to generate the rows but I wondered if there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @ThePhysicist: My first query had a bug, I replaced it with a working version.

Answer (score 1):

The only way the planner has a chance to avoid sorting the whole table is if you have an index on the complete `ORDER BY` clause.

Then an index scan can be chosen to get the correct ordering, and the first ten result rows may be found quickly.