# Index scan for multicolumn comparison - non-uniform index column ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

This question is closely related to [Enforcing index scan for multicolumn comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617385/enforcing-index-scan-for-multicolumn-comparison)

The solution there is perfect, but seems to works only if all index columns have *same* ordering. This question is different because column b is **desc** here, and this fact stops from using row-syntax to solve the same problem. This is why I'm looking for another solution.

Suppose index is built for 3 columns `(a asc, b DESC, c asc)`, I want Postgres to:

1. find key [a=10, b=20, c=30] in that B-tree,
2. scan next 10 entries and return them.

If the index has only one column the solution is obvious:

```
select * from table1 where a >= 10 order by a limit 10
```

But if there are more columns the solution becomes much more complex. For 3 columns:

```
select * from table1
where a > 10 or (a = 10 and (b < 20 or b = 20 and c <= 30))
order by a, b DESC, c
limit 10;
```

**How can I tell Postgres that I want this operation?**

**And can I be sure that even for those complex queries for 2+ columns the optimizer will always understand that he should perform range-scan? Why?**

Comment: Very good question +1.

Comment: Have you tried when you select a and not *?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL implements tuples very thoroughly, (unlike half implementations found in Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, etc.). You can write your condition using "tuples inequality", as in:

```
select * 
from table1
where (a, -b, c) >= (10, -20, 30)
order by a, -b, c
limit 10
```

Please note that since the second column is in descending order, you must "invert" its value during the comparison. That's why it's expressed as `-b` and also, `-20`. This can be tricky for non-numeric columns such as dates, varchars, LOBs, etc.

Finally, the use of an index is still possible with the `-b` column value if you create an ad-hoc index, such as:

```
create index ix1 on table1 (a, (-b), c);
```

However, you can never force PostgreSQL to use an index. SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. You can *entice* it to do it by keeping table stats up to date, and also by selecting a small number of rows. If your `LIMIT` is too big, PostgreSQL may be inclined to use a full table scan instead.

Comment: This is all interesting. But we still cannot use the given index `(a ASC, b DESC, c ASC)` for the query  fully. Postgres reads all index tuples with `a >= 10` and ***filters*** the rest on the whole ROW value. An index on just `(a)` typically does a better job - with the notable exception of index-only scans where possible. And only *some* data types have a negator `-` defined. `text`, for instance, has none.

Comment: I agree, I don't see how you can use the index `(a, b DESC, c)`. Extending your second query with equalities and inequalities, is the only solution I see to use this index. But, yes, it gets cumbersome the more columns you add.

Comment: Your workaround with the expression index on `(a, (-b), c)` can work fully after all - if you adapt `ORDER BY` to match as well: **`order by a, -b, c`** (not `order by a, b desc, c)`. Then we get an index scan without additional `FILTER` step.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't implement tuples at all, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, your index on `(a ASC, b DESC, c ASC)` can still be used, but only based on the **leading expression `a`**. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)
- [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684)

It's usefulness is limited and Postgres will only use it if the predicate on `a` alone is selective enough (less than roughly 5% of all rows have `a >= 10`). (Or possibly to profit from an index-only scans where possible.) But all index tuples qualifying on only `a` have to be read and you will see a `FILTER` step in the query plan to discard non-qualifying rows - both adding additional cost. An index on just `(a)` typically does a better job as it's smaller and cheaper to maintain.

I have tried and failed in the past to make full use of an index with non-uniform sort order (`ASC` | `DESC`) like you display for ROW value comparison. I am pretty certain it's **not possible**. Think of it: Postgres compares whole row values, which can either be greater or smaller, but not both at the same time.

There are **workarounds** for datatypes with a defined negator (like `-` for numeric data types). [See the solution provided by "The Impaler"!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55618388/939860) The trick is to invert values and wrap it in an expression index to get uniform sort order for all index expressions after all - which is currently the only way to tap into the full potential of row comparison. Be sure to make *both* `WHERE` conditions and `ORDER BY` match the special index.

Comment: Yeah, I was debating on how to alternate `<=` and `>=` on a per column basis for the tuple comparison, but SQL is not expressive enough (yet?) to do so, afaik. +1