# How to form a WHERE condition matching multiple ORDER BY items?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model `Trade` that has columns `traded_at`, `price`, `amount`.

And there is a `default_order` for it like this.

```
scope :default_order, -> {
  order(traded_at: :desc, price: :asc, amount: :desc)
}
```

I want to filter the `trades` by using this order clause.

This is my code for it without order clause.

```
scope :newer_than, ->(trade) {
  where(<<-SQL)
    traded_at > '#{trade.traded_at.to_s(:db)}' OR
    (traded_at = '#{trade.traded_at.to_s(:db)}' AND price < #{trade.price}) OR
    (traded_at = '#{trade.traded_at.to_s(:db)}' AND price = #{trade.price} AND amount > #{trade.amount})
  SQL
}
```

When I add one more `ORDER BY` item, I need to add 4 conditions in `WHERE` clause. Etc. The number grows binomially.
I think it's not efficient. Is there a more efficient way to translate multiple `ORDER BY` expressions into a matching `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres supports the concept of [**`ROW` values**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS).

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (a, b, c) > (1, 2, 3)  -- not for you!
```

But there is a **hitch**: every field in the row is compared in the same sense of ordering. Your case has mixed sort order (`ASC` / `DESC`), which is a showstopper. But if `price` is a numeric data type (seems like a safe bet) - which has a **negator** defined, there is a workaround:

```
... WHERE (a, -b, c) > (1, -2, 3)  -- for you
```

So:

```
where(<<-SQL)
    (traded_at, -price, amount)
  > ('#{trade.traded_at.to_s(:db)}', #{trade.price} * -1 , #{trade.amount})
  SQL
```

Or pass `trade.price` readily negated and drop `* -1`.

Can even be supported with a multicolumn expression index!

Note: None of this works properly with **NULL values** since those never qualify in your `WHERE` clause.

Related:

- [Index scan for multicolumn comparison - non-uniform index column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618108/index-scan-for-multicolumn-comparison-non-uniform-index-column-ordering/55619398)
- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)