# Compare date and seconds to timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have a Postgres table that stores created timestamp in a `created_date DATE` column and a `created_time INT` column holding seconds since midnight.

**EDIT**: The table is on a customer's production db and stores data from an older system, its not possible to make schema changes.

I would like to make a selection based on created timestamp.

In MySQL I would write:

```
SELECT * FROM MyCustomers
WHERE ADDTIME(created_date,SEC_TO_TIME(created_time)) > 'sometimestampliteral'
```

How would that look in PostgreSQL?

I can see examples in the manual, but they are all using literal values and not values from table columns.

Comment: I am curious as to the rationale for not having a timestamp column that just stores both these values.

Comment: I agree with Thom: it would be much better to store this in a single `timestamp` column

Comment: `'somedateliteral'` is meant to be a `'timestamp_literal'`, I suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the two together:

```
created_date + created_time * interval '1 second' > ?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `make_interval()` to turn the seconds into an interval which in turn can be added to a `date` column to construct a proper `timestamp`:

```
created_date + make_interval(secs => created_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

### While stuck with your design

Assuming [ISO format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TIME-TABLE) for `'somedateliteral'`.
Since it's supposed to be a timestamp literal, I'll name it `'timestamp_literal'` instead.

```
SELECT *, created_date + make_interval(secs => created_time) AS created_at
FROM   mycustomers
WHERE  (created_date, created_time)
     > (date 'timestamp_literal', EXTRACT(epoch FROM time 'timestamp_literal')::int);
```

`date 'timestamp_literal'` and `time 'timestamp_literal'` take the respective date / time part from the literal. (The latter breaks if there is no time part, while the former works with a date literal as well, obviously.)

#### Why?

To make it "sargable". See:

- [What does the word “SARGable” really mean?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217983/3684)

Contrary to solutions computing a timestamp on the fly ¹, this query can use a basic [**multicolumn index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html):

```
CREATE INDEX multicolumn_created ON mycustomers (created_date, created_time);
```

(¹ You *could* create a matching expression index to make it work ...)

Postgres can make perfect use of this index with **ROW value comparison**. (Last time I looked, MySQL couldn't do this.) See:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)
- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

### Proper fix

Storing timestamps as `date` + `integer` typically is a design error without benefits. Use `timestamp` instead. You may want to switch to the generally preferred `timestamptz` while being at it. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Other answers already provided expressions to convert `(date, integer)` to `timestamp` - which you can use to fix your table:

```
BEGIN;

-- drop all depending objects: indexes, views, ...

ALTER TABLE mycustomers
   ALTER created_date TYPE timestamp
      USING (created_date + make_interval(secs => created_time)) 
 , DROP COLUMN created_time;

ALTER TABLE mycustomers RENAME created_date TO created_at;  -- or whatever

-- recreate all depending objects: indexes, views, ...

COMMIT;
```

Adopt all queries using those columns, obviously. The query at hand simply becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM mycustomers WHERE created_at > 'somedateliteral';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=78afce903921e35f85dc522f4da5474a)*