# Find rows with all columns duplicated and no unique field in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, duplicates, postgresql-performance

Say I have a table like this, where no column or combination of columns is guaranteed to be unique:

| GAME_EVENT | USERNAME | ITEM | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sell | poringLUVR | sword | 1 |
| sell | poringLUVR | sword | 1 |
| kill | daenerys | civilians | 200000 |
| kill | daenerys | civilians | 200000 |
| invoke | sylvanas | undead | 1000000 |

And I want to retrieve the list of all rows that exist more than once (where the combination of ALL their columns appears more than once).

(In this case I would expect to get a list with the "sell/poringLUVR" and "kill/daenerys" rows)

What would be a good way of approaching this? Would a combined index be of any help? Suggestions for non-Postgres approaches are also welcome.

Comment: Your actual table definition is always instrumental for any such question (would tell us about `NOT NULL` constraints, among other things). And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all columns `NOT NULL`, this will do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl t2
   WHERE  (t1.*) = (t2.*)
   AND    t1.ctid <> t2.ctid
   );
```

[`ctid` is a system column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html), the "tuple identifier" / "item pointer" that can serve as poor-man's PK in the absence of an actual PK (which you obviously don't have), and only within the scope of a single query. Related:

- [Delete duplicate rows from small table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-rows-from-small-table/63759611#63759611)
- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66007/3684)

If columns can be `NULL`, (more expensively) operate with `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` instead of `=`. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

`(t1.*) = (t2.*)` is comparing *ROW values*. This shorter syntax is equivalent: `t1 = t2` unless a column of the same name exists in the underlying tables, in which case the second form fails while the first won't. See:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)

#### Index?

If any of the columns has a particularly high cardinality (many distinct values, few duplicates), let's call it `hi_cardi_column` for the purpose of this answer, a plain btree index on just that column can be efficient for your task. A combination of a few, small columns with a multicolumn index can work, too. The point is to have a small, fast index or the overhead won't pay.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl t2
   WHERE  t1.hi_cardi_column = t2.hi_cardi_column -- logically redundant
   AND    (t1.*) = (t2.*)
   AND    t1.ctid <> t2.ctid
   );
```

The added condition `t1.hi_cardi_column = t2.hi_cardi_column` is logically redundant, but helps to utilize said index.

Other than that I don't see much potential for index support as all rows of the table have to be visited anyway, and all columns have to be checked.