# How to avoid cross product/Cartesian/full join in SQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, join, cartesian-product

We have a table **A** with column "ETA To Destination" in minutes.

| id | ETA To Dest (mins) | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 |  |
| 2 | 75 |  |

There is a configuration table where we have defined scores based on the time intervals.

For example - If the
ETA is between 31 to 60 mins, score is 5 points,
ETA is between 61 to 120 mins, score is 10 points,

| From Time | To Time | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 30 | 2 |
| 31 | 60 | 5 |
| 61 | 120 | 10 |

We need to find the score (in table **A**) based on the ETA minutes in the configuration table (between from and to time).

I do not want to write a full join that will do a sequential scan in the table. Is there a better alternative or a better design.

Table **A** can have million of records and configuration table can have few more additional time interval rows.

Comment: Could you focus more on what you are trying to achieve instead of one possible solution? For example, can the scores change in time? How is the score used ie.: is there a report summarising milions of records or sth? Is the schema already in place and you need to optimise the queries without changing it?

Comment: Considering the schema is already in place, is there a better way to achieve the score without using full join ? We will sort it based on the score and show it. There is no other requirement.

Comment: You are not going to "show" millions of rows. What are you doing *exactly*? Show your version of Postgres, the exact table definition of `A` and the desired result - obviously just a few rows, not millions of them.

Comment: we will sort the records and will show top 50 records in a paginated order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.eta, s.score
FROM   a
JOIN   score_tbl s ON a.eta BETWEEN s.from_time AND s.to_time
ORDER  BY a.eta DESC NULLS LAST  -- how to break ties??
LIMIT  50;
```

With a **matching index** on `a(eta)` to support this query, it's a matter of milliseconds. The `LIMIT 50` you mentioned in a comment makes all the difference. Ideally:

```
CREATE INDEX a_eta_id_idx on a (eta DESC NULLS LAST) INCLUDE (id);
```

We can keep it that simple because higher `eta` correlates to higher `score`.

Details depend on undisclosed information. Basically, ***any***  B-tree index with `eta` as leading or only column will do. But you'll have to match yet undisclosed specifications how to break ties.

`DESC NULLS LAST` only if `eta` can be `null` (isn't defined `NOT NULL`). Else just `DESC`. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

If there can be duplicates on `eta`, you'll have to define how to break ties. My query makes an arbitrary pick. But that won't be good enough for proper pagination. See:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I too have similar query, want to check if there is any other better option. Seems like we need to use join with eta and from time and to time.