# SQL query with two IN statement to behave respectively

Tags: sql

I'm looking to optimise an SQL query with two `IN` conditions in the `WHERE` clause and preserve the original behavior. For example:

New query:

```
select * from empl
where age in (50,65) and location in ('Panama','Nigeria');
```

Original query:

```
Select * from empl
where (age = 50 and location = 'Panama') or (age = 65 and location  = 'Nigeria');
```

Problem: The original query returns 2 rows, but the new query clubs all the ages and location in the `IN` condition and returns multiple rows.

How to optimize this properly?

Comment: Do you mean age exactly 50 or 65, or do you mean age **between** 50 and 65? Do you need to select on gender at all, given that almost everyone will identify as one of those two options. What about people who don't?

Comment: The age is exact, updated gender with a different where condition, kindly check

Comment: If the query can be updated to replace gender with some arbitrary places around the world then the whole premise makes no sense. The age selection is bizarre. There's something you're not telling us. Voting to close as needing details or clarity.

Comment: What database are you using? You tagged a bunch.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test equality for age and location in lockstep like in your original query, use ROW values in **Postgres**. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM empl
WHERE (age, location) IN ((50,'Panama'), (65,'Nigeria'));
```

See:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)

Aside: `age` is typically bad design and should be replaced with something like `birthday`.

Comment: MySQL also supports this syntax. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/row-constructor-optimization.html