# Keyset pagination with alternating sort order within the set of keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, keyset-pagination

I have a table called `event` which has `id` (uuidv4), `name`, `description`, `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

I am trying to understand "keyset pagination". This is what I understand right now:

Base query (first page):

```
SELECT * 
FROM event 
ORDER BY created_at, id ASC 
LIMIT 3
```

Second query (second page):

```
SELECT * 
FROM event 
WHERE (created_at, id)
    > ('2024-02-09 14:21:52+00', '7aa20cad-3a8f-45cb-bee2-2115d4ad1c20') 
ORDER BY created_at, id ASC 
LIMIT 3;
```

This works perfectly. But I have a few use-cases which I don't understand.

1. What happens when I want to order by `created_at DESC` or `id DESC`?
2. How does it work if I want to order by `name DESC`?
   `SELECT * from event ORDER BY name DESC, created_at, id ASC LIMIT 3`. But how does that work when fetching with a cursor? I know that I have to include the name in the cursor but I don't understand how the tuple filter then would look like:

   ```
    SELECT * 
    FROM event 
    WHERE (name, created_at, id)
        > ('Name 9', '2024-02-09 14:21:52+00', '7aa20cad-3a8f-45cb-bee2-2115d4ad1c20') 
    ORDER BY created_at, id ASC 
    LIMIT 3;
   ```

   Like this? But does the `<` or `>` operator not correlate to the ordering?

Can someone point to resources explaining it well, or explain it here?

Comment: 1) I don't see `CURSOR` anywhere in your code. 2) Not sure what ordering on `uuidv4` is going to accomplish?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver cursor: (created_at, id) > ('2024-02-09 14:21:52.584146+00', '7aa20cad-3a8f-45cb-bee2-2115d4ad1c20'). All tutorials i can find about cursor pagination with uuid says to include it?

Comment: @TheImpaler With cursor pagination i mean on the api level. So the cursor would include the created_at, id values and we order on that in the database.

Comment: [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html): *uuid_generate_v4 () → uuid Generates a version 4 UUID, which is derived entirely from random numbers.* So I repeat what does ordering on a random value get you?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver "The key chosen must be unique"  this is a requirement? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se

Comment: @TheImpaler i mean keyset pagination. It's called cursor pagination in the api. So in the database we use keyset pagination.

Comment: Do you ever have two (or more) rows with the same timestamp(6) value?

Comment: @jarlh I don't know if that can happen?

Comment: So why bother about the UUID?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think the `id` is added there only for uniqueness purposes, not relevant for ordering.

Comment: A `uuid` by definition is unique, so you never have more then one `created_at, id` combination so ordering by `id` serves no purpose. Also since `uuidv4` generates random values `id by DESC` really has no meaning.

Comment: OK, now that we have established you are talking about keyset pagination and the ordering is UNIQUE, then you need to keep a consistent ordering. If you want ordering by `created_at DESC, id DESC`, then use `WHERE (created_at, id) < (last-values)`.

Comment: Finally, if you have mismatching orderings (blend between ASC and DESC), then you can negate the DESCs, and always use `<` in the `WHERE` clause. However, this works only for ordered domains, such as numbers, dates, and timestamps. I answered about this case a few years back here in stackoverflow; cannot find my answer anymore...

Comment: @TheImpaler the basic is easy and works. However my question was what happens when we add more sorting. For example on name?

Comment: If all of the sorting columns use the same ordering direction (either ASC or DESC), then use `>` or `<` respectively in the `WHERE` clause, for one, two, or a dozen ordering columns. Easy. If the sorting directions are different, that's another story.

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah i'm more about the part where the sorting directions are different. It seems that if i use > or < based on the first ordering it does work however

Comment: `>` if all orderings are ASC; `<` if all orderings are DESC.

Comment: There is no good way to mix ordering in a tuple comparator.  You could use subtraction to turn the time into an inverted interval and sort the intervals in descending order.  I don't know what you can do for the UUID, but if that just an arbitrary tie breaker, maybe you can just reverse the order of that comparison.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Appending a unique key as last item serves as tie breaker. We need deterministic sort order. (Wouldn't make sense to have more items *after* that.)

Answer (score 0):

"Keyset pagination" with index support (the only kind that performs well) is based on [**Row Constructor Comparison**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON). The comparison uses the same operator for every field in the row ("key in the set"). And the index has to agree with that: use the same fields in the same sequence and all with either ascending or descending sort order. **You cannot mix ascending and descending order in either the query or the index.** See:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)
- [Efficient pagination for big tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219810/3684)

Consequently, **beware of columns that aren't defined `NOT NULL`** in the row value (the "keyset") used for sorting. `NULL` sorts last in default `ASCENDING` sort order (and first ind `DESCENDING` order), but a row value comparison like:

```
WHERE (name, created_at, id) > ('Name 9', '...', '...')
```

... **excludes rows with null values in the `name` completely**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON)

> For the `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` cases, the row elements are compared
> left-to-right, stopping as soon as an unequal or null pair of elements
> is found. If either of this pair of elements is null, the result of
> the row comparison is unknown (null); otherwise comparison of this
> pair of elements determines the result. For example, `ROW(1,2,NULL) < ROW(1,3,0)` yields true, not null, because the third pair of elements
> are not considered.

Comment: To be clear: the keyword `ASC`, short for `ASCENDING`, is optional noise in the `ORDER BY` clause as that is the default direction.

Comment: So, basically the first order by direction determines it also for the others?

Comment: @Arjen: If you want to put it like that. You do have to spell out `DESC` for each `ORDER BY` item, though.

Comment: You can just use `AND` `OR` logic instead.

Comment: @Charlieface: You can. Doesn't mean you should. The syntax gets verbose and confusing quickly for more than two columns. And, more importantly, performance scales much worse. For performance optimization, projecting SQL Server knowledge to Postgres is not exactly reliable. Postgres has an optimized implementation for row value comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix the ordering then you can't use tuple/row comparison, **you need explicit `AND/OR` conditions**. This is not necessarily worse performance-wise (at least on SQL Server, I don't know about Postgres). It's just more verbose. The server should hopefully just use separate index seeks and concatenate them.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM event 
WHERE (
  name = @last_name
  AND created_at = @last_created_at
  AND id > @last_id
) OR (
  name = @last_name
  AND created_at > @last_created_at
) OR (
  name < @last_name
)
ORDER BY
  name DESC, 
  created_at ASC,
  id ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

You could mix and match, so use `AND/OR` for some columns and tuple comparison for others.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM event 
WHERE (
  name = @last_name
  AND (created_at, id) > (@last_created_at, @last_id)
) OR (
  name < @last_name
)
ORDER BY
  name DESC, 
  created_at ASC,
  id ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

**Note that three things must align** for Keyset Pagination to work properly, they all need to be the same:

- The index, which in this case should be `(name DESC, created_at ASC, id ASC)`
- The `ORDER BY`.
- The `WHERE` clause.

The index could be in reverse order, on DBMSs that support reverse index seeking (are there any that don't?). So you could have an index `(name ASC, created_at DESC, id DESC)` also.