Supabase can't use TEMP TABLE in functions used in views?
I am trying to use temp tables inside functions. I am using this function inside a view.
When viewing it inside the Supabase table viewer everything works, but when trying to use the view in the front end, Supabase is telling me the 405 error.
Language is plpgsql, every function is volatile, PostgREST version 12.0.2, Postgres version 15.1.1.9
Here is the function with the temp tables:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_working_minutes(
    p_user_id UUID,
    p_start_date DATE,
    p_end_date DATE
) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
    v_working_day_count INT := 0;
    v_date RECORD;
    v_model_id BIGINT;
    v_is_working_day INT;
BEGIN
    -- Step 1: Retrieve all relevant working time model assignments for the user
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_model_assignments AS
    SELECT working_time_model_id, year, month
    FROM types_working_time_model_assignment_records
    WHERE user_id = p_user_id
      AND (year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_end_date) 
          OR (year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_end_date) AND month <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p_end_date)))
    ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;

    -- Step 2: Retrieve the relevant working time models
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_working_time_models AS
    SELECT id, 
           sunday_working_day, 
           monday_working_day, 
           tuesday_working_day, 
           wednesday_working_day, 
           thursday_working_day, 
           friday_working_day, 
           saturday_working_day
    FROM types_working_time_models
    WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT working_time_model_id FROM temp_model_assignments);

    -- Step 3: Loop through the dates and calculate working days
    FOR v_date IN (SELECT generate_series(p_start_date, p_end_date, '1 day'::INTERVAL)::DATE AS g_date)
    LOOP
        -- Check if there are any model assignments
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_model_assignments) THEN
            -- Retrieve the working time model ID for the current date
            SELECT working_time_model_id
            INTO v_model_id
            FROM temp_model_assignments
            WHERE (year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date.g_date) 
                  OR (year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date.g_date) AND month <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v_date.g_date)))
            ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
            LIMIT 1;

            -- Determine if the current date is a working day based on the retrieved model ID
            SELECT (
                CASE 
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 0 AND sunday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 1 AND monday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 2 AND tuesday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 3 AND wednesday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 4 AND thursday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 5 AND friday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 6 AND saturday_working_day THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) INTO v_is_working_day
            FROM temp_working_time_models
            WHERE id = v_model_id;

            v_working_day_count := v_working_day_count + v_is_working_day;
        ELSE
            -- If there are no model assignments, count the day as 0 working day
            v_working_day_count := v_working_day_count + 0;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Drop temporary tables
    DROP TABLE temp_model_assignments;
    DROP TABLE temp_working_time_models;

    RETURN v_working_day_count;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

I have also created a second function that does not use temp tables:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_working_minutes(
    p_user_id UUID,
    p_start_date DATE,
    p_end_date DATE
) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
    v_working_day_count INT := 0;
    v_date RECORD;
    v_model_id BIGINT;
    v_is_working_day INT;
BEGIN
    -- Step 3: Loop through the dates and calculate working days
    FOR v_date IN (SELECT generate_series(p_start_date, p_end_date, '1 day'::INTERVAL)::DATE AS g_date)
    LOOP
        -- Check if there are any model assignments
        IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM types_working_time_model_assignment_records
            WHERE user_id = p_user_id
              AND (year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date.g_date) 
                  OR (year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date.g_date) AND month <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v_date.g_date)))
        ) THEN
            -- Retrieve the working time model ID for the current date
            SELECT working_time_model_id
            INTO v_model_id
            FROM types_working_time_model_assignment_records
            WHERE user_id = p_user_id
              AND (year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date.g_date) 
                  OR (year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date.g_date) AND month <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM v_date.g_date)))
            ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
            LIMIT 1;

            -- Determine if the current date is a working day based on the retrieved model ID
            SELECT (
                CASE 
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 0 AND sunday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 1 AND monday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 2 AND tuesday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 3 AND wednesday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 4 AND thursday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 5 AND friday_working_day THEN 1
                    WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM v_date.g_date::DATE) = 6 AND saturday_working_day THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) INTO v_is_working_day
            FROM types_working_time_models
            WHERE id = v_model_id;

            v_working_day_count := v_working_day_count + v_is_working_day;
        ELSE
            -- If there are no model assignments, count the day as 0 working day
            v_working_day_count := v_working_day_count + 0;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN v_working_day_count;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

When I use the second version in my view, I can access everything and do not get a 405 error. What could be the reason? I request the view with GET. Not using temp tables would be realy bad because otherwise the function would be realy inperformant. How someone can help me.
Edit:
I also found some more information about this:
Log Event Message
cannot execute CREATE TABLE AS in a read-only transaction

Log Metadata
[
  {
    "file": null,
    "host": "###",
    "metadata": [],
    "parsed": [
      {
        "application_name": "postgrest",
        "backend_type": "client backend",
        "command_tag": "SELECT",
        "connection_from": "###",
        "context": "SQL statement \"CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_model_assignments AS\r\n    SELECT working_time_model_id, year, month\r\n    FROM types_working_time_model_assignment_records\r\n    WHERE user_id = p_user_id\r\n      AND (year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_end_date) \r\n          OR (year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_end_date) AND month <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p_end_date)))\r\n    ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC\"\nPL/pgSQL function calculate_working_days(uuid,date,date) line 8 at SQL statement\nPL/pgSQL function calculate_working_minutes(uuid,date,date) line 10 at assignment",
        "database_name": "postgres",
        "detail": null,
        "error_severity": "ERROR",
        "hint": null,
        "internal_query": null,
        "internal_query_pos": null,
        "leader_pid": null,
        "location": null,
        "process_id": ###,
        "query": "WITH pgrst_source AS ( SELECT \"public\".\"view_timetracking_weekly\".* FROM \"public\".\"view_timetracking_weekly\"     LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2 )  SELECT null::bigint AS total_result_set, pg_catalog.count(_postgrest_t) AS page_total, coalesce(json_agg(_postgrest_t), '[]') AS body, nullif(current_setting('response.headers', true), '') AS response_headers, nullif(current_setting('response.status', true), '') AS response_status, '' AS response_inserted FROM ( SELECT * FROM pgrst_source ) _postgrest_t",
        "query_id": ###,
        "query_pos": null,
        "session_id": "###",
        "session_line_num": 3,
        "session_start_time": "2024-05-28 20:36:48 UTC",
        "sql_state_code": "25006",
        "timestamp": "2024-05-28 20:36:53.743 UTC",
        "transaction_id": 0,
        "user_name": "authenticator",
        "virtual_transaction_id": "###"
      }
    ],
    "parsed_from": null,
    "project": null,
    "source_type": null
  }
]


"Supabase is telling me the 405 error." Tell us more about this error. Preferably the verbatim error message. And provide the complete function definition, i.e. a complete, valid CREATE FUNCTION statement. Cutting off the head is unhelpful. And always declare your version of Postgres, please.

In Postgres temporary tables are scoped to the session they are created in. If you try to access from another session you will not see the tables. Per CREATE TABLE: PostgreSQL instead requires each session to issue its own CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE command for each temporary table to be used.

If you are after global temporary tables then you might want to look at this extension PostgreSQL Global Temporary Tables.

Added the full function and SQL versioning.
I am only accessing the temp tables inside this function, not outside. So I am not accessing the tables outside the session and dont need to.

And I also added more information about the error in the edit at the bottom.

Actually reading error messages can be enlightening. The transaction cannot be read-only. But most everything else can be improved, too. You might not need temp tables, or looping, or even a function at all ... For starters, consider much more efficient row-value comparison (year, month) <= (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p_end_date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p_end_date)) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982895/939860. Better yet, replace year and month with a single date column ...
