# Amount of data in database for certain field (column)

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Is it possible to get information about amount of data in one field  (column) in mysql or any other db?

Comment: What sort of information? Storage space used? Row count? Average value?

Comment: What kind of field? Most fields have a size associated with their data type.

Comment: What do you mean by 'amount of data'? How many bytes a table takes up? Or how many rows there are? Or... ?

Comment: That means storage space

Comment: RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a `varchar` type, this will tell you the number of bytes used by the column:

```
select sum(length(column_name)) + count(*) as total_bytes from table_name;
```

For `varchar`, you add 1 byte per row (ie add `count(*)`).

If it's `char`, simply multiply count(*) by the column width.

Answer (score 2):

The actual **on disc space requirement of a column for the whole table** is generally hard to determine. It depends on a number of factors.

#### About **PostgreSQL** in particular

- One of those factors is data alignment. I wrote more about that in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860).
- Another one is compression. Text that is longer than a few dozen bytes will be [toasted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html). I.e. compressed and stored in a in a separate TOAST table.
- Indexes add to total space requirement.

#### Answer by example

I use a real life table with 21k locations named `location` for the purpose. It has 20 columns, but `name` is the biggest one. To demonstrate the overhead a table carries, I created a temporary table with just the one column `name` in addition. (Overhead for a temp table is basically the same as for a plain table - I tested.)

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x AS SELECT name FROM location;
```

Then I used some of PostgreSQL's [**database object size functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) to create this demo:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('loc'::regclass)) AS tbl_size
      ,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('loc'::regclass)) AS rel_size
      ,(SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(loc))) from loc) AS sum_col_size

      ,pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('x'::regclass)) AS tbl_size
      ,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('x'::regclass)) AS rel_size
      ,(SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(loc))) from x) AS sum_col_size
```

Result:

```
tbl_size | rel_size | sum_col_size | x_tbl_size | x_rel_size | x_sum_col_size
---------+----------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------
3160 kB  | 3128 kB  | 432 kB       | 1104 kB    | 1096 kB    | 432 kB
```

---

But maybe I over-interpreted the question and you only want the storage size for basic data types? That's listed with every chapter in the fine manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html).