# Extracting the month and year from a Timestamp on a Unique check?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a table with a timestamp column. The problem is, I want the month and the year combination to be unique. I tried this, but it doesn't help:

```
CREATE TABLE adempiere.SOIP_Deudas (
    --Columnas del sistema
    SOIP_Deudas_ID      numeric(10)     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ad_client_id    numeric(10)     NOT NULL,
    ad_org_id   numeric(10)     NOT NULL,
    updatedby   numeric(10)     NOT NULL,
    createdby   numeric(10)     NOT NULL,
    updated     timestamp       NOT NULL,
    created     timestamp       NOT NULL,
    isactive    char(1)     DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar NOT NULL,

    --Columnas del usuario
    SOIP_Departamentos_ID numeric(10) NOT NULL,
    fecha       timestamp   NOT NULL,
    monto       real        NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    FOREIGN KEY (SOIP_Departamatos_ID) REFERENCES SOIP_Departamentos(SOIP_Departamentos_ID),
    UNIQUE (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP fecha), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP fecha))
)
```

Any idea of how I could do that without having specific Year and Month columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick workaround:

```
create unique index on adempiere.SOIP_Deudas ( EXTRACT (MONTH FROM fecha), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha));
```

Comment: A variation on this which might be a tiny bit faster would be to index on `(date_trunc('month', fecha))`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Comment: @kgrittn Or: `date_trunc('month', fecha)::date`, because  `datetrunc()` returns a timestamp and we only need a date (8 vs. 4 bytes -> index size). However, due to [data alignment & padding, the saved 4 bytes go to waste](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860) unless you have additional columns in the index.

Comment: Either way, it will be important to write the queries such that you are comparing with the same data type as you wind up with in the index.

Comment: Actually, you'd have to use `cast(date_trunc('month', fecha) AS date)`, as the `::` operator is not supported in index creation.

Comment: When i try doing this it gives me an error saying "ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE"