# How select data from two column in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in postgresql as follow:

```
id |   name   | parent_id |
1  | morteza  |   null    |
2  |   ali    |   null    |
3  | morteza2 |     1     |
4  | morteza3 |     1     |
```

My unique data are records with `id=1,2`, and record `id=1` modified twice. now I want to select data with last modified. Query result for above data is as follow:

```
id |   name   |
1  | morteza3 |
2  |   ali    |
```

What's the suitable query?

Comment: how you think this is latest record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am following correctly, you can use `distinct on` and `coalesce()`:

```
select distinct on (coalesce(parent_id, id)) coalesce(parent_id, id) as new_id, name
from mytable
order by coalesce(parent_id, id), id desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f94c9e5a24e2d2e823bfa3f22f0820b0)**:

```
new_id | name    
-----: | :-------
     1 | morteza3
     2 | ali
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it would seem that the latest version of each row has `parent_id IS NULL`. (And obsoleted row versions have `parent_id IS NOT NULL`.)

The query is simple then:

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM   tbl
WHERE  parent_id IS NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=33818df458ae43ac301b9b6c55b8cf47)*

If you have many updates (hence, many obsoleted row versions), a partial index will help performance a lot:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl(id) WHERE parent_id IS NULL;
```

The actual index column is mostly irrelevant (unless there are additional requirements). The `WHERE` clause is the point here, to exclude the many obsoleted rows from the index. See:

- [Postgres partial index on IS NULL not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/230087/3684)
- [Slow PostgreSQL query in production - help me understand this explain analyze output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639323/slow-postgresql-query-in-production-help-me-understand-this-explain-analyze-ou/11641119#11641119)