# Create index on first 3 characters (area code) of phone field?

Tags: postgresql, casting, indexing

I have a Postgres table with a phone field stored as `varchar(10)`, but we search on the area code frequently, e.g.:

```
select * from bus_t where bus_phone like '555%'
```

I wanted to create an index to facilitate with these searches, but I got an error when trying:

```
CREATE INDEX bus_ph_3 ON bus_t USING btree (bus_phone::varchar(3));

ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "::"
```

My first question is, how do I accomplish this, but also I am wondering if it makes sense to index on the first X characters of a field or if indexing on the entire field is just as effective.

Comment: if you're going to the extent of creating an index, might as well just index the whole field.

Comment: For a phone # field, indexing the whole thing might make sense, but for indexing a larger field, the cost of building and maintaining that index might actually hurt performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, a **plain B-tree index** is **useless** for pattern matching with `LIKE` (`~~`) or regexp (`~`), even with left-anchored patterns, if your installation doesn't run on locale `"C"` - which is the typical case. Here is an overview over pattern matching and indices:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Create an index with the `varchar_pattern_ops` operator class (matching your `varchar` column) and be sure to [read the chapter on operator classes in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html).

```
CREATE INDEX bus_ph_pattern_ops_idx ON bus_t (bus_phone varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Your original query can use this index:

```
... WHERE bus_phone LIKE '555%'
```

Performance of a [functional index on the first 3 characters as described in the answer by @a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256183/939860) is pretty much the same in this case.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GBWY00ws)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7918a/1)</sub>

Generally, a [functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on relevant leading characters *would be* be a good idea, but your column has only 10 characters. Consider that the [overhead per tuple is already 28 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13570853/939860). Saving 7 bytes is just not substantial enough to make a big difference. Add the cost for the function call and the fact that [`xxx_pattern_ops` are generally a bit faster](https://petereisentraut.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/rethink-your-text-column-indexing-with.html).
In Postgres 9.2 or later the index on the full column can also serve as [covering index in index-only scans.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans)

However, the more characters in the columns, the bigger the benefit from a functional index.
You may even *have to* resort to a prefix index (or some other kind of hash) if strings get too long. There is a maximum length for indices. See:

- [Index max row size error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25140/3684)

*If* you decide to go with the functional index, consider using the `xxx_pattern_ops` variant for a small additional performance benefit. Be sure to read about the pros and cons [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) and in [Peter Eisentraut's blog entry](https://petereisentraut.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/rethink-your-text-column-indexing-with.html):

```
CREATE INDEX bus_ph_3 ON bus_t (left(bus_phone, 3) varchar_pattern_ops);
```

#### Explanation for error message

You'd have to use the [standard SQL cast syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) for functional indices. This would work - pretty much like the one with `left()`, but like @a_horse I'd prefer `left()`.

```
CREATE INDEX bus_ph_3 ON bus_t USING btree (cast(bus_phone AS varchar(3));
```

Comment: You are right, I should have mentioned `text_pattern_ops` to support the left anchored `LIKE` conditions

Answer (score 4):

When using `like '555%'` an index on the complete column will be used just as well. There is no need to only index the first three characters.

If you do want to index only the first 3 characters (e.g. to save space), then you could use the `left()` funcion:

```
CREATE INDEX bus_ph_3 ON bus_t USING btree (left(bus_phone,3));
```

But in order for that index to be used, you would need to use that expression in your `where` clause:

```
where left(bus_phone,3) = '555';
```

But again: that is most probably overkill and the index on the complete column will be good enough and can be used for other queries as well e.g. `bus_phone = '555-1234'` which the index on just the first three characters would not.

Comment: Because some users may be doing
    `where bus_phone::varchar(3)`
or other variations, I think your suggestion to index the entire column makes the most sense - thank you!

Comment: @user35581: `bus_phone::varchar(3)` doesn't really make sense. Why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: not to get on a tangent, but what's wrong with casting to `varchar(3)`?

Comment: @user35581: seems rather dubios to me - but that might be personal preference. I prefer stating what my intention is. In this case I think using a `substr()` or `left()` makes it clear what the ultimate goal is. A type casting is  primarily to change the *type* of a value, not it's length. It's code smell to me (but again: this can be seen as personal preference or coding style)

Comment: @user35581: I added an explanation for the error message you got. But I agree with a_horse and prefer `left()` for a functional index.