# Cast syntax to convert a sum to float

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, type-conversion, postgresql-9.3

Using PostgreSQL 9.3, I want to convert the calculated values to data type `float`.

My first attempt:

```
SELECT float(SUM(Seconds))/-1323 AS Averag;
```

Gives me this error:

> ```
> syntax error at or near "SUM"
> ```

My second attempt:

```
SELECT to_float(SUM(Seconds))/-1323 AS Averag;
```

Gives me this error:

> ```
>  function to_float(bigint) does not exist
> ```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to use the `cast` syntax:

```
SELECT CAST (SUM(Seconds) AS FLOAT)/-1323 AS Averag;
```

Comment: What is the difference between `CAST` and `CONVERT`?

Comment: In PostgreSQL, `cast` is used for type conversions (e.g., `int` to `float`, like this example does) and `convert` is used to change string encondings.

Answer (score 110):

I use the shorthand cast syntax almost everywhere:

```
SELECT sum(seconds)::float / -1323 AS averag;
```

More details:

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. But what is the best way to cast. Is that using `::` or using `CAST` ?

Comment: @MAK: Both do the same. I *[almost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552825/postgres-using-an-index-for-one-table-but-not-another/28555617#28555617)* always use the shorter and clearer (IMO) `::target_type`. Follow the link in my question and in this comment, you'll find everything there is to know.

Comment: for this case, is "float" is the same as "double precision"?

Comment: what i mean is, is it 8-byte?

Comment: @Kokizzu: Yes. `float` = `float8` = `double precision`. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Answer (score 6):

It is not exact casting but a trick to do the job :) and works almost in any language.

> SELECT SUM(Seconds)/-1323.0 AS Averag;

OR

> SELECT SUM(Seconds)*1.0/-1323 AS Averag;