# Division ( / ) not giving my answer in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, division, modulo

I have a table `software` and columns in it as `dev_cost`, `sell_cost`. If `dev_cost` is 16000 and `sell_cost` is 7500, how do I find the quantity of software to be sold in order to recover the `dev_cost`?

I have queried as below:

```
select dev_cost / sell_cost from software ;
```

It is returning 2 as the answer. But we need to get 3, right?

What would be the query for that?

Comment: If sell_cost is 7500, we need to sell 3 software to recover dev_cost i.e. > 16000. That is my question

Comment: try `select ceil(16000::numeric/7500)`

Comment: select ceil(dev_cost::numeric/sell_cost) from software; --worked

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Your columns have integer types, and [integer division truncates the result towards zero](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html).  To get an accurate result, you'll need to [cast at least one of the values to float or decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736227/postgresql-9-3-convert-to-float):

```
select cast(dev_cost as decimal) / sell_cost from software ;
```

or just:

```
select dev_cost::decimal / sell_cost from software ;
```

You can then round the result up to the nearest integer using the `ceil()` function:

```
select ceil(dev_cost::decimal / sell_cost) from software ;
```

(See [demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dd9ec/1/0).)

Comment: We're talking about money. Cast to decimal, not float.

Comment: @Mike: Good point, although unlikely to matter in the OP's case. (All they're asking for is integer division that rounds up; floats will do just fine as an intermediate type for that, at least unless the original values are bigints.) Still, fixed.

Comment: @MRah: Glad to be of assistance. :) BTW, instead of commenting on answers that you find useful, you can vote them up by clicking the upwards-pointing triangle icon in the top left corner of the answer. This will reward the answerer with reputation points and lets them know that their answer is appreciated, and it also [helps the best answers rise to the top of the page.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 12):

You can cast integer type to `numeric` and use [`ceil()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) function to get the desired output

> The PostgreSQL ceil function returns the smallest integer value that
>   is greater than or equal to a number.

```
SELECT 16000::NUMERIC / 7500 col 
      ,ceil(16000::NUMERIC / 7500)
```

Result:

```
col                  ceil 
------------------   ---- 
2.1333333333333333     3
```

So your query should be

```
select ceil(dev_cost::numeric/sell_cost) 
from software
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also cast your variable to the desired type, then apply division:

```
 SELECT (dev_cost::numeric/sell_cost::numeric);
```

You can round your value , and specify the number of digits after point:

```
SELECT TRUNC((dev_cost::numeric/sell_cost::numeric),2);
```

Comment: Is there any real need to use ::decimal for each operand?

Answer (score 0):

This query will round result to next integer

```
select round(dev_cost ::decimal / sell_cost + 0.5)
```

Comment: This will give the wrong result if `dev_cost` happens to be an integer multiple of `sell_cost`: [see example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56439/1/0).

Comment: This query is ok. But if the table more values, say for example, dev_cost is 6000 and sell_cost is 400, the answer 15 would be correct. But your query gives 16 as the answer. What should we do? I am new to SQL, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Either round() or floor(x + 0.5), but not round(x + 0.5)