# Percent between two field PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 fields which are called game_series_count, game_series_wins and game_series_lost. I need to find wins percent.

```
select
       "game_series_count",
       "game_series_wins",
       "game_series_lost",
       round(( (game_series_wins / game_series_count) * 100), 1) as win_percent
from "statistic_teams"
```

but there is wrong result

```
game_series_count | game_series_wins | game_series_lost | win_percent
2   1   1   0
2   1   1   0
2   1   1   0
2   1   1   0
1   1   0   100
1   1   0   100
1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0
```

Comment: Mention the data types of the columns

Comment: integer. all of them

Comment: remove the round function and try.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504497/division-not-giving-my-answer-in-postgresql

Comment: looks like you already found :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division.  The simplest method for your purpose is probably:

```
   round(game_series_wins * 100.0 / game_series_count, 1) as win_percent
```

Note that you can also economize on parentheses.