# Cast integer to decimal in DQL

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, dql

I use Doctrine with a Postgres database and want to update the integer field "voting".
It's a procentual value, saved as integer between 0 and 100, based on the two integer fields "voteCountPro" and "voteCount".
I have to cast one of the integers to a decimal value. (See: [Division ( / ) not giving my answer in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504497/division-not-giving-my-answer-in-postgresql))
This doesn't work in DQL and fails with the message:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 363: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ':'

```
UPDATE statement s
SET s.voting = (s.voteCountPro::decimal / s.voteCount) * 100
WHERE s.id = :id
```

How can I set the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install https://github.com/oroinc/doctrine-extensions, register the CAST function and write:

```
UPDATE statement s
SET s.voting = (CAST(s.voteCountPro as decimal) / s.voteCount) * 100
WHERE s.id = :id
```