# Can't set value to column conditionally

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following code throws a `can't calculate log of zero` error even though I check for that case in `x != N`

```
DO $$
DECLARE N integer;
BEGIN
    select count(*) from mytable INTO N;
    UPDATE
        words
    SET
    measure = 
         CASE 
            WHEN x != N THEN 1 + log((N - x) / x)
            ELSE 0
         END;   
END $$;
```

also tried this, same error:

```
DO $$
DECLARE N integer;
BEGIN
    select count(*) from mytable INTO N;
    UPDATE words
    SET measure = 1 + log((N-x)/x)
    WHERE x <> N;   
END $$;
```

Comment: What's the datatype for x ? If that's an integer, (N-x)/x might become 0.

Comment: @FrankHeikens it is indeed an integer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause is in the "(N-x)/x" part: Since both 'N' and 'x' are integers,
the result is rounded down to the nearest integer (which is always 0 for positive 'N-x' and 'x').

BTW, this is a duplicate question:

[Division ( / ) not giving my answer in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504497/division-not-giving-my-answer-in-postgresql/34504552)