# percentage difference when using CASE WHEN clause POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, case, percentage, difference

**Is this the correct syntax?**
I am using the traditional method of (new/old)-1 to work out the % difference between yesterday's registrations and a week from yesterday's registrations. I am getting '0' which does not seem right...

```
select
sum(case when (timestampregistered::date = current_date - 1) then 1 else 0 end)
    / sum(case when timestampregistered::date = current_date - 8 then 1 else 0 end) - 1 as pct_diff
from customers_table
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division ( / ) not giving my answer in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504497/division-not-giving-my-answer-in-postgresql)

Comment: ah yes thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing integer arithmetics, so your answers will be integers.
Try

```
[...]then 1.0 else 0.0 end
```