# calculate into new column as percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

Very new and learning SQL. Trying to calculate a percentage from two columns as such:

```
Select (total_deaths/total_cases)*100 AS death_percentage
From covid_deaths
```

I’m getting the column but it’s showing as an Integer and all values are zero.

I’ve tried using CAST to make it a decimal but i don’t have the syntax right. Very noob question but seems simple enough. Do I have to declare the numeric type of all calculated columns?

Comment: does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504497/division-not-giving-my-answer-in-postgresql

Comment: Ok casting one of the values as opposed to the function, I think that’s what I had wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: This also works, *multiply first then divide*:  `100 * total_deaths/total_cases` returns an INT.  Use `round(100. * total_deaths/total_cases, 2)` for fractional digits.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the answer linked by Stefan Zivkovik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504497/division-not-giving-my-answer-in-postgresql) in a comment above, it may be good to handle division by zero.  Even if you don't ever anticipate `total_cases` will be zero, someone may reuse this part of the code (for instance, if `total_cases` is later broken into subcategories).

You probably also want to `ROUND` to a certain number of decimal places

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN total_cases > 0 THEN
    ROUND((total_deaths::NUMERIC/total_cases)*100,1)
  END AS death_percentage
FROM covid_deaths
```

By not specifying an `ELSE` clause, the column will be null when `total_cases` is zero.  If this doesn't work for your purposes, you could specify another default value (like zero) with `ELSE`.