# What indexes do I need to speed up AND/OR SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

Let's assume I have a table named `customer` like this:

```
+----+------+----------+-----+
| id | name | lastname | age |
+----+------+----------+-----+
| .. | ...  |   ....   | ... |
```

and I need to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ((name = 'john' OR lastname = 'doe') AND age = 21)
```

I'm aware of how single and multi-column indexes work, so I created these ones:

```
(name, age)
(lastname, age)
```

Is that all the indexes I need?

The above condition can be rephrased as:

```
... WHERE ((name = 'john' AND age = 21) OR (lastname = 'doe' AND age = 21)
```

but I'm not sure how smart RDBMS are, and if those indexes are the correct ones

Comment: Why not perform some diagnostics against the queries? I.e. if you're using SQL Server use the execution plan and see if the indexes save cost.

Comment: Short of putting the whole table into an index I dont think there much optimization that can be done for that query

Comment: @Mihai my table have much more fields than that... that's just an example.

Comment: @DarrenDavies unfortunately I don't have enough data to measure tests... and I'm not aware of any tool that can tell me if that is currently working in my db schema or not .

Comment: Questions concerning indexing or performance may depend on your version of Postgres. *Always* provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is reasonable. Two factors are essential here:

1. Postgres can combine multiple indexes very efficiently with bitmap index scans.

   - [PostgreSQL versus MySQL for EAV structures storage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14965/3684)
2. B-tree index usage is by far most effective when *only leading* columns of the index are involved.

   - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)
   - [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684)

#### Test case

If you `don't have enough data to measure tests`, you can always whip up a quick test case like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (id int, name text, lastname text, age int);

INSERT INTO customer
SELECT g
     , left(md5('foo'::text || g%500) , 3 + ((g%5)^2)::int)
     , left(md5('bar'::text || g%1000), 5 + ((g%5)^2)::int)
     , ((random()^2) * 100)::int
FROM   generate_series(1, 30000) g; -- 30k rows for quick test case
```

For your query (reformatted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer
WHERE (name = 'john' OR lastname = 'doe')
AND    age = 21;
```

I would go with

```
CREATE INDEX customer_age_name_idx ON customer (age, name);
CREATE INDEX customer_age_lastname_idx ON customer (age, lastname);
```

However, depending on many factors, a *single* index with all three columns and age as first may be able to deliver similar performance. The rule of thumb is to create as few indexes as possible and as many as necessary.

```
CREATE INDEX customer_age_lastname_name_idx ON customer (age, lastname, name);
```

The check on `(age, name)` is potentially slower in this case, but depending on selectivity of the first column it may not matter much.

[**Updated SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b2456/4)

#### Why `age` first in the index?

This is not very important and needs deeper understanding to explain. But [since you ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196058/what-indexes-do-i-need-to-speed-up-and-or-sql-queries/27198406?noredirect=1#comment42899414_27198406) ...

The order of columns doesn't matter for the 2-column indexes `customer_age_name_idx` and `customer_age_lastname_idx`. Details and a test-case:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684)

I still put `age` first to stay consistent with the 3rd index I suggested `customer_age_lastname_name_idx`, where the order of columns **does matter** in multiple ways:

**Most importantly**, both your predicates `(age, name)` and `(age, lastname)` share the column `age`. B-tree indexes are (by far) most effective on leading columns, so putting `age` first benefits both.

And, less importantly, but still relevant: the size of the index is smaller this way due to data type characteristics, alignment, padding and page layout of index pages.

`age` is a 4-byte `integer` and must be aligned at multiples of 4 bytes in the data page. `text` is of variable length and has no alignment restrictions. Putting the integer first or last is more efficient due to the rules of "column tetris". I added another index on `(lastname, age, name)` (`age` in the middle!) to the fiddle just to demonstrate it's ~ 10 % bigger. No space lost to additional padding, which results in a smaller index. And **size matters**.

For the same reasons it would be better to **reorder columns in the demo table** like this: `(id, age, name, lastname)`. If you want to learn why, start here:

- [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43142/3684)
- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23933/3684)

Everything I wrote is for the case at hand. If you have other queries / other requirements, the resulting strategy may change.

#### `UNION` query equivalent?

Note that a `UNION` query may **or may not** return the same result. It folds duplicate rows, which your original does not. Even if you don't have *complete* duplicates in your table, you may still see this effect with a subset of columns in the `SELECT` list. Do not blindly substitute with a `UNION` query. It's *not* going to be faster anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response ;) I have a quick question... why does it matter, in my query, `(age, name)` vs `(name, age)`?

Comment: @OscarMederos: Well, it doesn't really matter for the 2-column index. But it matters for the 3-column index - and also for the underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the OR into two queries UNIONed:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Age = 21 AND Name = 'John'
UNION
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Age = 21 AND LastName = 'Doe'
```

Then create an index over (Age, Name) and another over (Age, LastName).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know I could do that, but that's not exactly my question...

Comment: Yes, those are the indexes. But it is recommended to use UNION instead of OR.

Comment: @RicardoPeres: That "recommendation" is news to me. Who's recommending that?

Comment: http://www.databasechannel.com/AccessArticles/Article_ORAND_UseUnionInsteadofOR.html

Comment: The `UNION` could be optimal for sqlserver, but it definitely is slower for Postgres. (and the `UNION` should at least be an `UNION ALL`)

Comment: You are right about UNION ALL, my fault. But like I said, and there are lots of links about it, the performance of UNION os gwnerally better, for normal cases.

Comment: Your [1st link](http://www.databasechannel.com/AccessArticles/Article_ORAND_UseUnionInsteadofOR.html) is for Access 2007 (!), your [2nd](http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/using-union-instead-of-or) and [3rd](http://sqltouch.blogspot.pt/2013/03/or-vs-union-all-have-you-thought-about.html) are for SQL Server. All of them address implementation details of the respective MS products and are irrelevant for Postgres (or other SQL implementations).

Comment: @wildplasser: `UNION ALL` may or may not be "better". It's even further away from the original as `UNION`. The former potentially adds additional duplicate rows in the result, the latter may remove duplicates. Neither *generally* guarantees an identical result to the original query. If the original query never returns duplicate rows, `UNION` can emulate it, but ***not*** `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Except for the performance part: `UNION` is terrible.