# Altering column type from int to bigint frees space?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, storage, postgresql-9.5, vacuum

I have table with an `int` type column, in a table of ~ 15 M rows.
OS windows 7 and C disk (where postgres is installed) shows that:

> 59 GB free of 238 GB

Then I changed this column type to `bigint`:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER column col TYPE bigint;
```

And now, C disk:

> 61 GB free of 238 GB

How are 2 GB freed? Looks like that `bigint` would take less space than `int`? Or what happened?

There is no other processes on this machine (this is local/home computer) at this moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bigint` takes 8 bytes, `int` takes 4 bytes, but space on disk depends on the whole row.

- [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)

More importantly, the physical size of the file containing the table also depends on dead tuples (table bloat). `VACUUM` (typically only `VACUUM FULL`) can reduce the physical size of the table. Your `ALTER TABLE` caused a whole-table rewrite, which *bloated* the table. But it also made it simple for a later `VACUUM` (or `VACUUM FULL`) to trim data pages with only dead tuples - effectively compacting the table. `VACUUM` is run by `autovacuum` automatically with default settings (but not `VACUUM FULL`).

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system/37032#37032)
- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/are-regular-vacuum-analyze-still-recommended-under-9-1)

Apart from that side effect, changing a column from `int` to `bigint` *never* reduces the row size (without bloat). Sometimes it stays the same because the previous row had 4 bytes of alignment padding that can be used by the `bigint`. Or the row size increases by another (typically) 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity - only `VACUUM FULL` can reduce disk space used by table. And even this not always true - depend on amount of deleted tuples in datafile pages if some pages can be removed. And it creates new datafile.

Plain `VACUUM` only frees space in existing datafile pages by removing deleted tuples but does not lower number of allocated pages in datafile. And does not create new datafile.

Comment: Actually, plain `VACUUM` *does* opportunistic pruning of removable data pages at the end of the physical file. [Details with quotes and links to the manual here.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684)