# Why does Postgres not use better index for my query?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, sql-order-by, postgresql-performance

I have a table where I keep record of who is following whom on a Twitter-like application:

```
\d follow
                               Table "public.follow" .
 Column   |           Type           |                      Modifiers
 ---------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
xid       | text                     |
followee  | integer                  |
follower  | integer                  |
id        | integer                  | not null default nextval('follow_id_seq'::regclass)
createdAt | timestamp with time zone |
updatedAt | timestamp with time zone |
source    | text                     |
Indexes:
  "follow_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
  "follow_uniq_users" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (follower, followee)
  "follow_createdat_idx" btree ("createdAt")
  "follow_followee_idx" btree (followee)
  "follow_follower_idx" btree (follower)
```

Number of entries in table is more than a million and when I run explain analyze on the query I get this:

```
explain analyze SELECT "follow"."follower"
FROM "public"."follow" AS "follow"
WHERE "follow"."followee" = 6
ORDER BY "follow"."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0;
                                                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=0.43..353.69 rows=15 width=12) (actual time=5.456..21.497 
rows=15 loops=1)
->  Index Scan Backward using follow_createdat_idx on follow  (cost=0.43..61585.45 rows=2615 width=12) (actual time=5.455..21.488 rows=15 loops=1)
     Filter: (followee = 6)
     Rows Removed by Filter: 62368
Planning time: 0.068 ms
Execution time: 21.516 ms
```

Why it is doing backward index scan on `follow_createdat_idx` where it could have been more faster execution if it had used `follow_followee_idx`.

This query is taking around 33 ms when running first time and then subsequent calls are taking around 22 ms which I feel are on higher side.

I am using Postgres 9.5 provided by Amazon RDS. Any idea what wrong could be happening here?

Comment: Because if it did a lookup on the followee index it would then have to do a sort. If this is the primary use of the follow_followee index you might want to try adding createdAt as a second field on that index.

Comment: @user1937198 After I did this, computation time went down from 20 ms to 2ms. So it worked. Any performance implications If I leave both `"follow_createdat_idx" btree ("createdAt")` index and newly created `"follow_follower_createdat_idx" btree (follower, "createdAt")` index. Because in some use cases I need to get just all users a person is following where first index may be more optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multicolumn index on `(follower, "createdAt")` that [user1937198 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833559/why-postgres-not-using-better-index-in-my-query#comment74704128_43833559) is perfect for the query - as you found in your test already.

Since `"createdAt"` can be NULL (not defined `NOT NULL`), you may want to add **`NULLS LAST`** to query *and* index:

```
...
ORDER BY "follow"."createdAt" DESC NULLS LAST
```

And:

```
"follow_follower_createdat_idx" btree (follower, "createdAt" DESC NULLS LAST)
```

More:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

There are ***minor*** other performance implications:

- The multicolumn index on `(follower, "createdAt")` is 8 bytes per row bigger than the simple index on `(follower)` - 44 bytes vs 36. More (btree indexes have mostly the same page layout as tables):

  - [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853)
- Columns involved in an index in any way cannot be changed with a HOT update. Adding more columns to an index *might* block this optimization - which seems particularly unlikely given the column name. And since you have another index on just `("createdAt")` that's not an issue anyway. More:

  - [PostgreSQL Initial Database Size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21014/postgresql-initial-database-size/21507#21507)
- There is no downside in having another index on just `("createdAt")` (other than the maintenance cost for each (for write performance, not for read performance). Both indexes support different queries. You may or may not *need* the index on just `("createdAt")` additionally. Detailed explanation:

  - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)