# How to execute database-function on external big file, with no copy

Tags: postgresql, performance, blob

The test below shows that it is possible, but I am not verified performance (comparing for example with Bash or Python), and I don't understand exactly how to do or what happens:

- The [lo_import/lo_get](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-funcs.html) (in my `test_lo_proc`) created a copy of the file, or can it be used as (I supposed) an external reference?
- Is it necessary to do `lo_unlink`?
- The alternative, [pg_read_binary_file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) as commented by @a_horse_with_no_name, is not limited in file size?

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION test_lo_proc(
  file_name text
) RETURNS text AS $f$
 DECLARE
  doc_oid oid;
  md5 text;
 BEGIN
  doc_oid = lo_import(file_name);
  md5 = md5(lo_get(doc_oid));
  -- ? lo_unlink(doc_oid)
  RETURN md5;
 END;
$f$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;

SELECT test_lo_proc('/tmp/bigbigfile.zip');
```

PS: the MD5 is to compare performance (with `md5sum *.zip` for example), real-life function use for example `MD5(lo_content||metadata::bytea)` or something more complex using internal database resources... I am **not** looking for external execution (when you can use `COPY t FROM PROGRAM`).

Comment: It seems like you have found a way. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Using a large object seems overkill just to calculate the MD5 hashsum. Why not use [pg_read_binary_file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE)

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, sorry my English... The main question is "I do correct?  I am doing with **no copy**?", and the secondary question is "I need  lo_unlink?"

Comment: Yes, you need to unlink. I'll look at the rest later.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, good clue and alternative. .. I was avoiding pg_read functions because seems there is a restriction for big  files, as in `pg_read_file` limited to  922337203 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two better alternatives:

1. Like the horse suggested, use [`pg_read_binary_file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) to read the file into memory and calculate a checksum with the `md5` function.

   The disadvantage is that you have to read the whole file into memory.
2. Write a PL/PerlU or PL/Python function that calculates the checksum of the file. That will probably perform better. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3431825/6464308) is a Stackoverflow question that deals with that.