# Unique constraint for permutations across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, constraints, unique-constraint

Given the following three columns in a Postgres database: first, second, third; how can I create a constraint such that permutations are unique?

E.g. If `('foo', 'bar', 'shiz')` exist in the db, `('bar', 'shiz', 'foo')` would be excluded as non-unique.

Comment: I'd like to know this too. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Can your columns be NULL? Can they be empty? Define "unique" then. Your Postgres version? And I don't see a table definition for testing in your question?

Comment: Non null. 9.2.2 The values are all text.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to 9.2.4 to snuff out the security vulnerability patched in 9.2.4. More details at http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-1899

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use hstore to create the unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hidx ON test USING BTREE (hstore(ARRAY[a,b,c], ARRAY[a,b,c]));
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1f901/2)

### UPDATE

Actually

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hidx ON test USING BTREE (hstore(ARRAY[a,b,c], ARRAY[null,null,null]));
```

might be a better idea since it will work the same but should take less space ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b9b7a/1)).

Answer (score 6):

For only **three columns** this unique index using only basic expressions should perform very well. No additional modules like hstore or custom function needed:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_abc_uni_idx ON t (
  LEAST(a,b,c)
, GREATEST(LEAST(a,b), LEAST(b,c), LEAST(a,c))
, GREATEST(a,b,c)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U8YFxv9n)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2dc0b/1)</sub>

Also needs the least disk space:

```sql
SELECT pg_column_size(row(hstore(t))) AS hst_row
     , pg_column_size(row(hstore(ARRAY[a,b,c], ARRAY[a,b,c]))) AS hst1
     , pg_column_size(row(hstore(ARRAY[a,b,c], ARRAY[null,null,null]))) AS hst2
     , pg_column_size(row(ARRAY[a,b,c])) AS arr
     , pg_column_size(row(LEAST(a,b,c)
                        , GREATEST(LEAST(a,b), LEAST(b,c), LEAST(a,c))
                        , GREATEST(a,b,c))) AS columns
FROM t;
```

```
 hst_row | hst1 | hst2 | arr | columns
---------+------+------+-----+---------
      59 |   59 |   56 |  69 |      30
```

Numbers are bytes for index row in the example in the fiddle, measured with [`pg_column_size()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860). My example uses only single characters, the difference in size is constant.

Comment: Clever use of GREATEST and LEAST.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a unique index on a function which returns a sorted array of the values in the columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sorted_array(anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray
AS $BODY$
  SELECT array_agg(x) FROM (SELECT unnest($1) AS x FROM test ORDER BY x) AS y;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE UNIQUE index ON test (sorted_array(array[first,second,third]));
```

Comment: Might be worth checking what the performance impact of a couple of nested CASE expressions to manually sort would be too. With only 3 columns that should be viable. Might not be worth the extra time though.

Comment: Richard, performance not a driver here. Small app, maybe 20-100 inserts a day.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from co-worker, variation of @julien's idea:

Sort the terms alphabetically and place a delimiter on either side of each term. Concatenate them and place them in a separate field that becomes the primary key.

Why the delimiter? So that, "a", "aa", "aaa" and "aa", "aa", "aa" can both be inserted.