# Eliminate rows with columns with inverted values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am having so much trouble trying to work this out. Can somebody help me?

I have a table with colA and colB and these as the values for each row:

```
colA  ColB
2     1
1     2
```

When selecting in this table, I want to retrieve just one row since the values are inverted.
If 2 implies 1, 1 implies 2, so they are equal and I don't want two rows as a return.

Is there any way of doing a SQL query and get the result I want?
For example, just one row with colA = 1, colB = 2.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a row with more columns or just the two values? Is `(colA, colB)` unique? A table definition would clarify things. Version of Postgres, too.

Comment: If the permutations are considered duplicates, you might be better off with a [unique index](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18361539/939860) preventing such duplicates. [Related case for 3 columns.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18361539/939860)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is only 2 columns:

```
WITH t(colA, colB) AS (
    VALUES (1,2), (2,1)
)
SELECT DISTINCT least(colA, colB), greatest(colA, colB)
  FROM t;
```

**EDIT:** As outlined by Daniel, although this might do the job, this approach is not good for filtering as it'll change the original data.

Comment: This produces a (colB,colA) row when colA>colB even if there is no such row in the source table. It might solve the asker's problem or not, but that's not a filtering technique.

Comment: @DanielVérité, I don't understand this. Could you provide a sample, please?

Comment: Try with just one row as input: `VALUES (1,0)`. Result: `0,1`.

Answer (score 3):

No indication was made as to which version of the tuple is preferred over the other. I.e., we know that `(1,2)` is equivalent to `(2,1)` and in that case one of the two should be display, but which of the two? In this solution, the assumption is that the variant with the lower `ColA` value is preferred over the reverse.

```
Select ColA, ColB
From SourceData As S
Where ColA < ColB
    Or Not Exists   (
                    Select 1
                    From SourceData As S1
                    Where S1.ColA = S.ColB
                        And S1.ColB = S.ColA
                    )
```

Comment: ColA <= ColB would be better otherwise the query will ignore rows where ColA = ColB

Comment: @Multisync - There is no indication as to whether `ColA = ColB` is allowed or whether duplicates are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL [`SELECT ... EXCEPT SELECT ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) construct may be used for this. Also it will probably be faster than queries involving a self-join, especially without any index. I would suggest:

```
SELECT colA, colB FROM table
  EXCEPT
SELECT colB, colA FROM table WHERE colA < colB;
```

Duplicates rows are eliminated (if not needed or not desirable, use `EXCEPT ALL`).

Rows where colA=colB are not a special case, they go into the result, de-duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

A self join might work.

```
select t1.cola, t1.colb
from tablename t1 join tablename t2 on something
where t1.cola <> t2.colb
and t1.colb <> t2.cola
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using arrays?

```
select a, b from t;

/*
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
 2 | 1
(2 rows)
*/

create extension intarray;
select distinct sort(ARRAY[a, b]) from t;

/*    
 sort  
-------
 {1,2}
(1 row)
*/
```