# Add ID to duplicates in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, grouping

I have a table representing trade exchanges between cities and I'd like to add an id that would indicate groups of same origin/destination and destination/origin alike.

For example:

```
| origin | destination
|--------|------------
| 8      | 2
| 2      | 8
| 8      | 2
| 8      | 5
| 8      | 5
| 9      | 1
| 1      | 9
```

would become:

```
| id | origin | destination
|----|--------|------------
| 0  | 8      | 2
| 0  | 2      | 8
| 0  | 8      | 2
| 1  | 8      | 5
| 1  | 8      | 5
| 2  | 9      | 1
| 2  | 1      | 9
```

I can have same origin/destination but I can also have origin/destination = destination/origin and I want all of those groups identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way: with the window function [`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) and [`GREATEST` / `LEAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

```
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY GREATEST(origin, destination)
                                 , LEAST   (origin, destination)) - 1 AS id
     , origin, destination
FROM   trade;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=84e9a5d9ccd980b2c489882a2d62f791)*

`- 1` to start with 0 like your example.

Comment: Would `dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY array(SELECT unnest(array[origin, destination, ...]) ORDER BY 1))` be a reasonable way to generalize this to more than two columns?

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. 4 sec for a one million entry table !

Comment: @unutbu: Depends on exact definition of groups. With more than two columns, it spreads out like a *binomial distribution*. Is `(a,b,c)` supposed to match `(a,c,b)` as well as `(b,a,c)` etc.? Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361539/939860 If column order is irrelevant, it is still considerably more expensive to unnest, sort, aggregate like in your example (`ORDER BY 1 DESC` to stay in sync). While it's all `integer` I'd consider faster module `intarray` for this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870508/939860

Comment: @unutbu: With `dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY sort_desc(ARRAY[origin, destination, ...])) AS id`  See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6fd74f41d64005060041e60bdddd338f Really a valid new *question*.