# Why is my date dimension table useless? (Confusion over PostgreSQL storage...)

Tags: performance, postgresql, optimization, space-efficiency

I have looked over this about 4 times and am still perplexed with these results.

Take a look at the following (which I originally posted [here](http://junctionbox.ca/2013/04/09/calendar-tables-for-postgresql-data-warehousing/))

## Date dimension table --

```
-- Some output omitted

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dim_calendar CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE dim_calendar (
  id SMALLSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  day_id DATE NOT NULL,
  year SMALLINT NOT NULL, -- 2000 to 2024
  month SMALLINT NOT NULL, -- 1 to 12
  day SMALLINT NOT NULL, -- 1 to 31
  quarter SMALLINT NOT NULL, -- 1 to 4
  day_of_week SMALLINT NOT NULL, -- 0 () to 6 ()
  day_of_year SMALLINT NOT NULL, -- 1 to 366
  week_of_year SMALLINT NOT NULL, -- 1 to 53
  CONSTRAINT con_month CHECK (month >= 1 AND month <= 31),
  CONSTRAINT con_day_of_year CHECK (day_of_year >= 1 AND day_of_year <= 366), -- 366 allows for leap years
  CONSTRAINT con_week_of_year CHECK (week_of_year >= 1 AND week_of_year <= 53),
  UNIQUE(day_id)
);

INSERT INTO dim_calendar (day_id, year, month, day, quarter, day_of_week, day_of_year, week_of_year) (
  SELECT ts, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts),
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts),
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM ts),
  EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM ts),
  EXTRACT(DOW FROM ts),
  EXTRACT(DOY FROM ts),
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ts)
  FROM generate_series('2000-01-01'::timestamp, '2024-01-01', '1day'::interval) AS t(ts)
);

/* ==> [ INSERT 0 8767 ] */
```

## Tables for testing --

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS just_dates CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS just_date_ids CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE just_dates AS
  SELECT a_date AS some_date
  FROM some_table;

/* ==> [ SELECT 769411 ] */

CREATE TABLE just_date_ids AS
  SELECT d.id
  FROM just_dates jd
  INNER JOIN dim_calendar d
  ON d.day_id = jd.some_date;

/* ==> [ SELECT 769411 ] */

ALTER TABLE just_date_ids ADD CONSTRAINT jdfk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES dim_calendar (id);
```

## Confusion --

```
pocket=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('dim_calendar'));

pg_size_pretty 
----------------
448 kB
(1 row)

pocket=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('just_dates'));
pg_size_pretty 
----------------
27 MB
(1 row)

pocket=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('just_date_ids'));
pg_size_pretty 
----------------
27 MB
(1 row)
```

Why is a table consisting of a bunch of smallints the same size as a table consisting of a bunch of dates?  And I should mention that before, when `dim_calendar.id` was a normal `SERIAL`, it gave the same `27MB` result.

Also, and more importantly -- **WHY** does a table with `769411` records with a single smallint field have a size of `27MB`, which is `> 32bytes/record`???

P.S. Yes, I will have billions (or at a minimum hundreds of millions) of records, and am trying to add performance and space optimizations wherever possible.

## EDIT

This might have something to do with it, so throwing it out there --

```
pocket=# select count(id) from just_date_ids group by id;
 count  
--------
 409752
 359659
 (2 rows)
```

Comment: If you want to minimise space requirements then **why** are you storing all these derived fields in dim_calendar, where storing just the ts would suffice?

Comment: In the end I would.  Kind of besides the point.  This was just a test based on the dimension table created from the article in the page I linked.  Only interested in why the result is not as I expected...

Comment: And actually relative to the other tables, the extra space from those extra 7 columns are rather (completely, utterly) insignificant.

Comment: Sorry, had not seen the link. Still makes no sense (do you know that Postgres supports functional indexes?)

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand about my questions.  Refer to the foib's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tables with one or two columns, the biggest part of the size is always the Tuple Header.

Have a look here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-page-layout.html, it explains how the data is stored. I'm quoting the part of the above page that is most relevant with your question

> All table rows are structured in the same way. There is a fixed-size header (occupying 23 bytes on most machines), followed by an optional null bitmap, an optional object ID field, and the user data.

This mostly explains the question

> WHY does a table with 769411 records with a single smallint field have a size of 27MB, which is > 32bytes/record???

The other part of your question has to do with the byte alignment of postgres data. Smallints are aligned in 2-byte offsets, but ints (and dates of course... `date` is an `int4` after all) are aligned in 4 bytes offsets. So the order in which the table columns are devlared plays a significant role.

Having a table with smallint, date, smallint needs 12 bytes for user data (not counting the overhead), while declaring smallint, smallint, date only will need 8 bytes. See a great (and surprisingly not accepted) answer here [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql)