# Physical size of int2, int4, int8 in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, storage, postgresql-9.3, database-administration, alter

I am not understand differents between storage size of INTs (all this types has fixed size)

In official manual I see this description:

> The types smallint, integer, and bigint store whole numbers, that is,
>   numbers without fractional components, of various ranges. Attempts to
>   store values outside of the allowed range will result in an error.
>
> The type integer is the common choice, as it offers the best balance
>   between range, storage size, and performance. The smallint type is
>   generally only used if disk space is at a premium. The bigint type is
>   designed to be used when the range of the integer type is
>   insufficient.
>
> SQL only specifies the integer types integer (or int), smallint, and
>   bigint. The type names int2, int4, and int8 are extensions, which are
>   also used by some other SQL database systems.

However simple test shows that change type of column do not change table size

```
create table test_big_table_int (
  f_int integer
);

INSERT INTO test_big_table_int (f_int )
    SELECT ceil(random() * 1000)
        FROM generate_series(1,1000000);


 SELECT
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size_of_table"
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
 where relname = 'test_big_table_int';
 --"35 MB";


 alter table test_big_table_int ALTER COLUMN f_int TYPE bigint;


 SELECT
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size_of_table"
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
 where relname = 'test_big_table_int';
--"35 MB";

  alter table test_big_table_int ALTER COLUMN f_int TYPE smallint;


 SELECT
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size_of_table"
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
 where relname = 'test_big_table_int';
 --"35 MB";"0 bytes"
```

Everytime I get  size of my table - 35MB. So where the profit to use integer or smallint  insthead int8?

And second question - why postgee is doing rewrite tuple while change type of int  (int2<->int4<->int8)?

Comment: You should at least run VACUUM FULL after altering the schema, to give the database a chance to be compacted.

Comment: Already has tried. You will get same result if will do  vacuum full test_big_table_int; aftre every alter :-)

Comment: The columns are padded to word boundaries when stored on disk: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/330315