# Benchmark: bigint vs int on PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, postgresql, int, sqldatatypes, bigint

I want to increase my database performance. In a project, all tables went from `int` to `bigint`, which I think is a bad choice not only regarding storage, since `int` requires `4 bytes`, and `bigint` requires `8 bytes`;but also regarding performance.
So I created a small table with **10 millions** entries, with a script in `Python:`

```
import uuid

rows=10000000

output='insert_description_bigint.sql'
f = open(output, 'w')

set_schema="SET search_path = norma;\n"
f.write(set_schema)

for i in range(1,rows):
    random_string=uuid.uuid4()
    query="insert into description_bigint (description_id, description) values (%d, '%s'); \n"
    f.write(query % (i,random_string))
```

And this is how I created my `two` tables:

```
-- BIGINT

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS description_bigint;

CREATE TABLE description_bigint
(
  description_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(200),
  constraint description_id_positive CHECK (description_id >= 0)
);

select count(1) from description_bigint;
select * from description_bigint;
select * from description_bigint where description_id = 9999999;

-- INT

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS description_int;

CREATE TABLE description_int
(
  description_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(200),
  constraint description_id_positive CHECK (description_id >= 0)
);
```

After inserting all this data, I do a query for both tables, to measure the difference between them. And for my surprise they both have the same performance:

```
select * from description_bigint; -- 11m55s
select * from description_int; -- 11m55s
```

Am I doing something wrong with my benchmark ? Shouldn't `int` be faster than `bigint` ? Especially, when the `primary key` is by definition an `index` which means, to create an index for `bigint` would be **slower** than create an index for `int`, with the same amount of data, right ?

I know that is not just a small thing that will make a huge impact regarding performance on my database, but I want to ensure that we are using the best practices and focused into performance here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In a 64-bit system the two tables are nearly identical. The column `description_id` in `description_int` covers 8 bytes (4 for integer and 4 as alignment). Try this test:

```
select 
    pg_relation_size('description_int')/10000000 as table_int, 
    pg_relation_size('description_bigint')/10000000 as table_bigint,
    pg_relation_size('description_int_pkey')/10000000 as index_int,
    pg_relation_size('description_bigint_pkey')/10000000 as index_bigint;
```

The average row size of both tables is virtually the same. This is because the integer column occupies 8 bytes (4 bytes for a value and 4 bytes of alignment) exactly like bigint (8 bytes for a value without a filler). The same applies to index entries. This is a special case, however. If we add one more integer column to the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE two_integers
(
  description_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  one_more_int INT,
  description VARCHAR(200),
  constraint description_id_positive CHECK (description_id >= 0)
);
```

the average row size should remain the same because the first 8 bytes will be used for two integers (without filler).

Find more details in [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468).

Comment: Hi @klin, I got this result `76;76;22;22`; Would you mind to clarify it ?

Comment: @klin You seem to be using the word "bits" instead of "bytes" in many places.