# Can I use "char" as a replacement for Enum in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, enums, database-performance

I've an ever-growing table(~20 Million rows in a year).

The table has a `status` column which is `enum` type with 10 states like:

```
ENQUEUED, DELIVERED, FAILED, ...
```

Since Postgres `enum` type takes 4 bytes space, I decided to alter the column to something less needed space like `smallint` or `character(1)` or `"char"`.

```
enum           takes 4 bytes
smallint       takes 2 bytes
character(1)   takes 2 bytes
"char"         takes 1 byte
```

I want to use `"char"` with this values:

```
E, D, F, ...
```

Because `"char"` takes less space than `smallint` or `character(1)`

Is it good idea to use `"char"` as a less space replacement for `enum`?

Any ideas would be great appreciated.

Comment: Due to [alignment and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/330315) it probably won't make a difference

Comment: Agree with a_horse, still enum is the best choice for readability and code maintenance.

Comment: `character(1)` is 5 bytes, by the way

Comment: Use whatever is easiest for you to code and maintain. Speed and disks get cheaper and cheaper.. 1 byte, even multiplied 20 million times is not going to change anything you'll notice.

Comment: In addition to the already mentioned, I would always prefer Enums, because they are easier to understand (e.g. the meaning of `DELIVERED` is clearer than the meaning of `D`). They are ordered (e. g. `ENQUEUED` is less than `DELIVERED`) and you can often take advantage of this.

Comment: @NickBarnes source? Everything I'm reading says 1 byte overhead. Running `pg_column_size` on `CHAR(1)` appears to support this (every result is 2)

Comment: @Krusty: The source of the overhead is the `varlena` header. I'm still getting 5: https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zhmnt4bv

Comment: @NickBarnes interesting, probably a version / encoding difference. I'm running Postgres 10; didn't see a version on there (I probably didn't look hard enough)

Comment: @Krusty: It's version 14, though it was the same on 9.6: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/108943/0 . Encoding shouldn't factor into it, as the same `varlena` header is carried by all values of variable-length types (like `numeric`, arrays, etc.)