# Postgres. Can I expect a good speedup by switching BIGINT to INT

Tags: database, postgresql, database-indexes

This Postgres database got tables of all sizes up to 10 million rows. Almost all have a BIGINT primary key counting from 1 and up.

Since BIGINT is 64 bits, but 10 million rows are well within the 2 billion maximum of INT, would it be worthwhile converting those BIGINT columns into INT (32 bits) and SMALLINT (16 bits) to speed up some heavy duty SQLs? Storing indexes/tables more compactly should give us a higher cache hit ratio. How much of a speedup could I expect if any? And are there any disadvantages by not using BIGINT? (assuming reaching max of INT/SMALLINT will never be an issue)

Comment: "assuming reaching max of INT/SMALLINT will never be an issue" ... that's a big assumption. There is always someone that comes with the bright idea of adding "x millions/billions/whatever" to the PK to store temp records/v2 records/whatever, and since it worked so well the 1st time, let's do this routinely.

Answer (score 5):

It very much depends on actual table and index definitions. The switch saves 4 bytes for the column - but since all storage is done in multiples of 8 bytes, this may be swallowed by alignment padding or free up 8 bytes if you are lucky.

The standard btree index backing the PK won't change in size, 4 bytes are lost to alignment padding. *But* if you have use for an additional 4-byte column in a covering index, that saves 8 bytes instead of just 4, which makes the index tuple 20 bytes total instead of 28.

The `bigint` primary key is only the start. If there are foreign key references to it, effects are multiplied. Or you have multicolumn indexes involving multiple FK columns. Then the switch *can* very well result in a good speedup like you are looking for. Especially if cache memory is limited. It all depends.

If you are certain you won't burn more than 3^31 numbers (not 2^32: Postgres uses signed integer, you'd have to use the negative half too) over the lifetime of the table, *and* you actually save space in tables and indexes, then, by all means, switch to plain `integer`. I have seen an actual difference many times. But you need some understanding of Postgres storage mechanisms before you tinker with this.

Related:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43142/3684)

Answer (score 3):

Only a load test will give a reliable answer to that, but I expect that you won't see a noticeable performance gain.

`bigint` is the correct data type here. Even if you are certain that you won't exhaust the limit of `integer`, consider this:

- if you generate values using a sequence, you are likely not to use every possible number – transactions could be rolled back
- there once were a couple of smart people who thought that 2<sup>32</sup> would be way more IP addresses than anyone could ever possibly need

With a small table like yours, the savings in space and performance would not be worth the effort.  With a big table, you don't want to suffer the pain of having to convert it from `integer` to `bigint`.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

Data is generally stored on disk aligned to 8 byte boundaries.  A single column index is going to be the same size on bigint as it will be on int.  For a table or a multicolumn index, it might be able to pack int more tightly, depending what adjacent columns can be merged together to fit in 8 bytes.

The performance change is likely to be small or non-existent, and hard to predict.  To know the answer, you would have to do the test.  But it probably is not worth the time it would take to do it.