# Is it safe to use "char" (note the quotes) data type in PostgreSQL for production application?

Tags: postgresql, types, database-design

I have a column that stores a numeric value ranging from 1 to 5.

I considered using `smallint` and `character(1)`, but I feel like there might be a better data type that is `"char"` (note the quotes).

`"char"` requires only 1 byte, which led me to thinking a performance gain over `smallint` and `character(1)`.

However, in PostgreSQL's own [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html), it says that `"char"` is not intended for general-purpose use, only for use in the internal system catalogs.

Does this mean I shouldn't use `"char"` data type for my production application?

If so, which data type would you recommend to store a numeric value ranging from 1 to 5.

Comment: Heed the notes and don't use it. Use `smallint` with a `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: I very much doubt that in a real world database you will actually see a substantial difference between using `smallint` or `"char"` in terms of storage space. Use a smallint

Comment: @user330315 I store 384-dimensional vectors of type `"char"[]`. They occupy 408 bytes, so it's really one byte, while `smallint` is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The data type [**`"char"`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE) is a Postgres type that's not in standard SQL. It's "safe" and you can use it freely, even if *"not intended for general-purpose use"*. There are no restrictions, other than it being non-standard. The type is used across many system catalogs, so it's not going away. If you ever need to migrate to another RDBMS, make the target `varchar(1)` or similar.

`"char"` lends itself to 1-letter enumeration types that never grow beyond a hand full of distinct plain ASCII letters. That's how I use it - including productive DBs. (You may want to add a `CHECK` or `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to columns enforcing valid values.)

For a *"numeric value ranging from 1 to 5"* I would still prefer `smallint`, seems more appropriate for numeric data.

A storage benefit (1 byte vs. 2 bytes) only kicks in for multiple columns - and/or (more importantly!) indexes that can retain a smaller footprint after applying alignment padding.

Notable updates in Postgres 15, quoting the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-15.html):

> - Change the I/O format of type `"char"` for non-ASCII characters (Tom Lane)
>
>   Bytes with the high bit set are now output as a backslash and three
>   octal digits, to avoid encoding issues.

And:

> - Create a new `pg_type.typcategory` value for `"char"` (Tom Lane)
>
>   Some other internal-use-only types have also been assigned to this
>   category.

(No effect on enumeration with plain ASCII letters.)

Related:

- [Shall I use enum when are too many "categories" with PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258591/3684)
- [How to store one-byte integer in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159916/3684)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)

Comment: Doesn't the storage benefit kick in for arrays (i.e. `"char"[]` vs. `smallint[]`) with many elements? I described my case and the usage of `"char"[]` [here](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/issues/325).