# Adding a new column at certain place in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an existing table called schools and trying to add a `teachers` column as follows; however, I want to add `teachers` columns right before the `updated_at` column; therefore, my script is as follows. But when I run my script it does not do anything, wondering if I am doing something wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE schools rename to old_schools;
CREATE TABLE schools
(
    user_id character varying(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    status character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    teachers text [] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'
    updated_at bigint NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO schools
    (user_id, owner_id, status, updated_at)
select user_id, owner_id, status, updated_at
from old_schools;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a new Column in a table after the 2nd or 3rd column in the Table using postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243547/how-to-add-a-new-column-in-a-table-after-the-2nd-or-3rd-column-in-the-table-usin)

Comment: please be more informative about `dose not do anything` .  and by just looking into query there is no `owner_id` in new `schools` table.