# addAfterColumn is not allowed on postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, dockerfile, liquibase

To fix vulnerabilities I upgraded docker image version in my dockerfile:

**old:**

```
FROM liquibase/liquibase:4.4
```

**new**:

```
FROM liquibase/liquibase:4.20
```

But I started to get error:

```
addAfterColumn is not allowed on postgresql
```

I started to investigate this error and found out that in some changesets `addAfterColumn` is used.

```
<changeSet author="***" id="***">
    <addColumn tableName="my_table" >
      <column afterColumn="existing_column"
        name="new_column"
        type="varchar(255)" >
        <constraints nullable="true"/>
      </column>
    </addColumn>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I also found this topic:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3091

So I just removed `afterColumn` but I am not sure what side effects could I experience ? I am not familiar about reason to use `afterColumn` but if it is removed it could be useless but I can't find any useful information.

Are there any other options to fix the issue ? because editing liquibase scripts will break checksums for existing databases

Comment: Columns are always added "at the end" in Postgres. So if Liquibase accepted that attribute in a previous version it must have ignored it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but why ? people say that it makes sense
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243547/how-to-add-a-new-column-in-a-table-after-the-2nd-or-3rd-column-in-the-table-usin/14775092#14775092

Comment: Why? Because no one has implemented such a feature.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so it was a bug in previous version of liquibase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this pull request](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/2943) shows, previously liquibase did not warn that column ordering might not be applied, because the database does not support it. So it failed silently in older versions, but now it shows an error. Quoting the most important line:

> **Breaking change:** Because I fixed the validation logic, anyone who has a beforeColumn or afterColumn or position attribute on addColumn for a database that doesn't support that will now get a validation error vs. it just being ignored.

Comment: So they broke back compatibility without ability to disable this "enhancement". Crazy people

Answer (score 2):

remove "afterColumn" so it works in fresh ENV.
to avoid Validation failure in an ENV where the change set is already executed, adding the original checksum works:

```
  <changeSet>
    <validCheckSum>9:6a4c63a04890c57dd610abc39389b4ce</validCheckSum>
        or
    <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
```

Comment: Had the same issue with `addAutoIncrement  / incementBy` and the above solution fixes the problem properly. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do suggestion with `modifySql` from here:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3094#issuecomment-1195961510

```
<changeSet id="***" author="***">
    <addColumn tableName="my_table">
        <column name="new_column" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>
    <modifySql dbms="postgresql">
        <append value=" position 4"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

It looks like in liquibase 4.13 https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/2943 they fixed something that doesn't need to be fixed as in https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3091 they are trying to enhance/fix their own fix. In addition to breaking backward compatibility (as @gstackoverflow wrote in the comment), it breaks the logic when the product has support for many types of databases (no error for mySQL and error for Oracle/MsSQL/PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase 4.24.0 introduced [`removeChangeSetProperty`](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/remove-change-set-property.html) in order to address this issue. So, in your case the fix will be:

```xml
<removeChangeSetProperty change="addColumn" remove="afterColumn" dbms="postgresql" />
```

Keep in mind, that this line should be added to all changelogs where `afterColumn` was being used. There is a feature request to let it work with `include` and `includeAll` so it would be poss possible to declare it only once: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/5290

At time of writing, 24 Dec 2023, the issue is open.